# Truncate a list to a given number of elements

Tags: java, collections

What method truncates a list--for example to the first 100 elements--discarding the others (without iterating through individual elements)?

Comment: I found this question while looking for a way to trim a list to the first 10 elements in Kotlin lol. It turns out Kotlin defines the `.take(10)` method on Collections, which was sufficient for my case. (The other nice thing about `.take` is that it won't throw an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` if the list is less than 10 elements). Code: `myList.take(10).joinToString("\n", postfix = "\n")` etc.

Answer (score 158, accepted):

Use [`List.subList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#subList-int-int-):

```
import java.util.*;
import static java.lang.Math.min;

public class T {
  public static void main( String args[] ) {
    List<String> items = Arrays.asList("1");
    List<String> subItems = items.subList(0, min(items.size(), 2));

    // Output: [1]
    System.out.println( subItems );

    items = Arrays.asList("1", "2", "3");
    subItems = items.subList(0, min(items.size(), 2));

    // Output: [1, 2]
    System.out.println( subItems );
  }
}
```

You should bear in mind that `subList` returns a view of the items, so if you want the rest of the list to be eligible for garbage collection, you should copy the items you want to a new `List`:

```
List<String> subItems = new ArrayList<String>(items.subList(0, 2));
```

If the list is shorter than the specified size, expect an out of bounds [exception](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/IndexOutOfBoundsException.html). Choose the minimum value of the desired size and the current size of the list as the ending index.

Lastly, note that the second argument should be one more than the last desired index.

Comment: while the question is not exactly clear, it does sound like sam wants a the end of the list deleted. Therefore your answer should include a list.clear().

Comment: This is not likely to perform as well as karim79's solution, which is the best alternative - it has the best chance of performing well and is the cleanest code as well.

Comment: I think it depends on the number of elements to be removed (and also if the List supports modification)

Comment: If Java 8 is an option, I think `Stream.limit` should do the trick (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#limit-long-)

Answer (score 61):

```
list.subList(100, list.size()).clear();
```

or:

```
list.subList(0, 100);
```

Comment: The first option modifies the list while the second does not. It shoud be `list = list.subList(0, 100)`

Comment: Also note that `subList(100, list.size()).clear()` will only work if list has its clear method implemented, for example if you create `list` by `List<String> list = Arrays.asList(someString.split(","));` clear() will throw `UnsupportedOperationException` since `list` will be an abstract `List`.

Comment: If you would like to keep the initial n elements of the List, it should be `list.subList(n, list.size()).clear();`

Comment: Shame you have to create an object just to shorten a list

Comment: @DavidBradley True but HotSpot may actually optimize this away

Comment: This is simply wrong. subList creates a view on the original list - so messing around with this method will never actually clear the elements that should be discarded. They live on forever.

Answer (score 21):

`subList`, as suggested in the other answers, is the first that comes to mind. I would also suggest a [stream approach](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html).

```
source.stream().limit(10).collect(Collectors.toList()); // truncate to first 10 elements
source.stream().skip(2).limit(5).collect(Collectors.toList()); // discards the first 2 elements and takes the next 5
```