# Should we refer to objects by their interfaces in Android platform

Tags: java, android

I use to the advice given by Joshua Bloch's Effective Java, `Item 52: Refer to objects by their interfaces`.

However, in most of the sample code comes with Android, I realize the following code is quite common.

```
private ArrayList<Integer> mPhotos = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

I understand this is due to performance optimization purpose, as the following code will be slower.

```
private List<Integer> mPhotos = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

However, is such optimization technique still valid? As if I read from 
http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/design/performance.html

> On devices without a JIT, it is true that invoking methods via a variable with an exact type rather than an interface is slightly more efficient. (So, for example, it was cheaper to invoke methods on a HashMap map than a Map map, even though in both cases the map was a HashMap.) It was not the case that this was 2x slower; the actual difference was more like 6% slower. Furthermore, the JIT makes the two effectively indistinguishable.

Do we need to assume our devices are without JIT, and refer objects without interfaces? Or, shall we just adopt to Joshua Bloch's advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of Android 2.2, the Dalvik VM (that runs the Dalvik bytecode that is the result of your Java source code) has a Just-in-time compiler (JIT).

I don't know if this particular optimization is part of the JIT or not, but it should be testable on actual devices.

*If* you target pre-2.2 devices *and* those 6% overhead in invocation (which is not to be confused with an overal 6% slowdown of your application!) has a serious effect on your application, then that optimization might be worthwhile.

Answer (score -3):

```
private ArrayList<Integer> mPhotos = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

This is prefered, beyond performance reason. It's a private variable, use the most specific type known.

Comment: The reason is not concrete. It had nothing to do with private variable. Example provided by Joshua Bloch is also private.

Comment: I think is quite arrogant for you to say that. You at least need to provide some real world example and fact to support your statement. At least in Joshua Bloch's Effective Java, he do provide a very good real world example why using interface is better.

Comment: see my explanation earlier http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3978702/why-are-most-of-the-examples-using-arraylist/3979663#3979663

Comment: Even private variables could cause you pain if you swap out an implementation and it's all over your class.  This is terrible advice.