# How to create a Multidimensional ArrayList in Java?

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, arraylist

I need to create a multidemensional ArrayList to hold String values. I know how to do this with a standard array, like so: `public static String[][] array = {{}}` but this is no good because I don't know the size of my array, all I know is how many dimensions it will have.

How can I make a 'dynamically resizable array with 2/+ demensions'?

Edit/Update

---

Maybe it would be easier to resize or define a standard array using a varible? But I don't know?
It's probably easier to use my original idea of an ArrayList though... All I need is a complete example code to create a 2D ArrayList and add so example values to both dimensions without knowing the index.

Comment: Please take a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37016599/2457251

Answer (score 35, accepted):

`ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> array = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();`

Depending on your requirements, you might use a Generic class like the one below to make access easier:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

class TwoDimentionalArrayList<T> extends ArrayList<ArrayList<T>> {
    public void addToInnerArray(int index, T element) {
        while (index >= this.size()) {
            this.add(new ArrayList<T>());
        }
        this.get(index).add(element);
    }

    public void addToInnerArray(int index, int index2, T element) {
        while (index >= this.size()) {
            this.add(new ArrayList<T>());
        }

        ArrayList<T> inner = this.get(index);
        while (index2 >= inner.size()) {
            inner.add(null);
        }

        inner.set(index2, element);
    }
}
```

Comment: You should parameterize the interior ArrayList.

Comment: @Poindexter Thanks for providing the compilation warning.  :)

Comment: As always, thanks for the speedy reply's and I'm only commenting on this answer because It's the last one.

Comment: Hi, me again, Just wondered how I add values to the different dimensions. i.e. [1] = String 1 [2] = String 2

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see your edit! Thanks but I'm not quite sure what you mean, maybe a code example might help, please?

Answer (score 16):

If you're allowed to use predefined Java classes, you could do something like:

```
private static ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> biDemArrList = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
```

Then you can add new elements, something like:

```
ArrayList<String> temp = new ArrayList<String>(); // added () 
temp.add("Hello world.");
biDemArrList.add(temp);
```

Hope you can understand what I mean and what's going on. Also, you'll need to import java.util.ArrayList; for this, if you're making use of the Java class.

Answer (score 13):

`ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>`

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generics_in_Java

Answer (score 8):

Once I required 2-D arrayList and I created using List and ArrayList and the code is as follows:

```
import java.util.*;

public class ArrayListMatrix {

    public static void main(String args[]){

        List<ArrayList<Integer>> a = new ArrayList<>();

        ArrayList<Integer> a1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        ArrayList<Integer> a2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        ArrayList<Integer> a3 = new ArrayList<Integer>();


        a1.add(1);
        a1.add(2);
        a1.add(3);

        a2.add(4);
        a2.add(5);
        a2.add(6);

        a3.add(7);
        a3.add(8);
        a3.add(9);

        a.add(a1);
        a.add(a2);
        a.add(a3);


        for(ArrayList obj:a){

            ArrayList<Integer> temp = obj;

            for(Integer job : temp){
                System.out.print(job+" ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

**1 2 3**

**4 5 6**

**7 8 9**

Source : https://www.codepuran.com/java/2d-matrix-arraylist-collection-class-java/

Answer (score 4):

I can think of An Array inside an Array or a [Guava's MultiMap](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release03/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html)?

e.g.

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> matrix = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
```

Comment: Certainly not `Multimap`. That's a map-like construct, not a list-like one.

Answer (score 3):

You can have ArrayList with elements which would be ArrayLists itself.

Answer (score 3):

Wouldn't `List<ArrayList<String>> 2dlist = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();` be a better (more efficient) implementation?

Comment: If you're going with declaring `List` on the outside, seems like you'd want it on the inside as well, as `List<List<String>>`.

Comment: An ArrayList is a specific implementation of a List… using List on the inside wouldn't define the implementation and using ArrayList on the outside forces you to always use that implementation. Using List on the outside means that you could change the inside ArrayList later without having to change everywhere you used List on the outside… see: <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2279030/type-list-vs-type-arraylist-in-java>.

Comment: Actually, @ErickG.Hagstrom is correct. The answer geowar posted supports Erick's answer.

Answer (score 2):

Here an answer for those who'd like to have preinitialized lists of lists. Needs Java 8+.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

class Scratch {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int M = 4;
    int N = 3;

    // preinitialized array (== list of lists) of strings, sizes not fixed
    List<List<String>> listOfListsOfString = initializeListOfListsOfT(M, N, "-");
    System.out.println(listOfListsOfString);

    // preinitialized array (== list of lists) of int (primitive type), sizes not fixed
    List<List<Integer>> listOfListsOfInt = initializeListOfListsOfInt(M, N, 7);
    System.out.println(listOfListsOfInt);
  }

  public static <T> List<List<T>> initializeListOfListsOfT(int m, int n, T initValue) {
    return IntStream
        .range(0, m)
        .boxed()
        .map(i -> new ArrayList<T>(IntStream
            .range(0, n)
            .boxed()
            .map(j -> initValue)
            .collect(Collectors.toList()))
        )
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
  }

  public static List<List<Integer>> initializeListOfListsOfInt(int m, int n, int initValue) {
    return IntStream
        .range(0, m)
        .boxed()
        .map(i -> new ArrayList<>(IntStream
            .range(0, n)
            .map(j -> initValue)
            .boxed()
            .collect(Collectors.toList()))
        )
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
  }
}
```

Output:

```
[[-, -, -], [-, -, -], [-, -, -], [-, -, -]]
[[7, 7, 7], [7, 7, 7], [7, 7, 7], [7, 7, 7]]
```

Side note for those wondering about `IntStream`:

```
IntStream
    .range(0, m)
    .boxed()
```

is equivalent to

```
Stream
    .iterate(0, j -> j + 1)
    .limit(n)
```

Answer (score 1):

Credit goes for JAcob Tomao for the code.
I only added some comments to help beginners like me understand it.
I hope it helps.

```
// read about Generic Types In Java & the use of class<T,...> syntax
// This class will Allow me to create 2D Arrays that do not have fixed sizes    
class TwoDimArrayList<T> extends ArrayList<ArrayList<T>> {
    public void addToInnerArray(int index, T element) {
        while (index >= this.size()) {
            // Create enough Arrays to get to position = index
            this.add(new ArrayList<T>()); // (as if going along Vertical axis)
        }
        // this.get(index) returns the Arraylist instance at the "index" position
        this.get(index).add(element); // (as if going along Horizontal axis)
    }

    public void addToInnerArray(int index, int index2, T element) {
        while (index >= this.size()) {
            this.add(new ArrayList<T>());// (as if going along Vertical
        }
        //access the inner ArrayList at the "index" position.
        ArrayList<T> inner = this.get(index);
        while (index2 >= inner.size()) {
            //add enough positions containing "null" to get to the position index 2 ..
            //.. within the inner array. (if the requested position is too far)
            inner.add(null); // (as if going along Horizontal axis)
        }
        //Overwrite "null" or "old_element" with the new "element" at the "index 2" ..
        //.. position of the chosen(index) inner ArrayList
        inner.set(index2, element); // (as if going along Horizontal axis)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What would you think of this for 3D ArrayList - can be used similarly to
arrays - see the comments in the code:

```
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;

    /**
     * ArrayList3D simulates a 3 dimensional array,<br>
     * e.g: myValue = arrayList3D.get(x, y, z) is the same as: <br>
     *      myValue = array[x][y][z] <br>
     * and<br>
     *      arrayList3D.set(x, y, z, myValue) is the same as:<br> 
     *      array[x][y][z] = myValue; <br>
     * but keeps its full ArrayList functionality, thus its
     * benefits of ArrayLists over arrays.<br>
     * <br>
     * @param <T> data type
     */
    public class ArrayList3D <T> {

        private final List<List<List<T>>> arrayList3D;

        public ArrayList3D() {
            arrayList3D = newArrayDim1();
        }


                                            /**
                                             * Get value of the given array element.<br>
                                             * E.g: get(2, 5, 3);<br>
                                             * For 3 dim array this would equal to:<br>
                                             *      nyValue = array[2][5][3];<br>
                                             * <br>
                                             * Throws: IndexOutOfBoundsException
                                             * - if any index is out of range 
                                             *   (index < 0 || index >= size())<br>
                                             * <br>
                                             * @param dim1 index of the first dimension of the array list
                                             * @param dim2 index of the second dimension of the array list
                                             * @param dim3 index of the third dimension of the array list
                                             * @return value of the given array element (of type T)
                                             */
        public T get(int dim1, int dim2, int dim3) {
            List<List<T>>       ar2 = arrayList3D.get(dim1);
            List<T>             ar3 = ar2.get(dim2);
            return ar3.get(dim3);
        }


                                            /**
                                             * Set value of the given array.<br>
                                             * E.g: set(2, 5, 3, "my value");<br>
                                             * For 3 dim array this would equal to:<br>
                                             *      array[2][5][3]="my value";<br>
                                             * <br>
                                             * Throws: IndexOutOfBoundsException
                                             * - if any index is out of range 
                                             *   (index < 0 || index >= size())<br>
                                             * <br>
                                             * @param dim1 index of the first dimension of the array list
                                             * @param dim2 index of the second dimension of the array list
                                             * @param dim3 index of the third dimension of the array list
                                             * @param value value to assign to the given array
                                             * <br>
                                             */
        public void set(int dim1, int dim2, int dim3, T value) {
            arrayList3D.get(dim1).get(dim2).set(dim3, value);
        }

                                            /**
                                             * Set value of the given array element.<br>
                                             * E.g: set(2, 5, 3, "my value");<br>
                                             * For 3 dim array this would equal to:<br>
                                             *      array[2][5][3]="my value";<br>
                                             * <br>
                                             * Throws: IndexOutOfBoundsException
                                             * - if any index is less then 0
                                             *   (index < 0)<br>
                                             * <br>
                                             * @param indexDim1 index of the first dimension of the array list
                                             * @param indexDim2 index of the second dimension of the array list
                                             *        If you set indexDim1 or indexDim2 to value higher
                                             *        then the current max index,
                                             *        the method will add entries for the
                                             *        difference. The added lists will be empty.
                                             * @param indexDim3 index of the third dimension of the array list
                                             *        If you set indexDim3 to value higher
                                             *        then the current max index,
                                             *        the method will add entries for the
                                             *        difference and fill in the values
                                             *        of param. 'value'.
                                             * @param value value to assign to the given array index
                                             */

        public void setOrAddValue(int indexDim1, 
                                  int indexDim2,
                                  int indexDim3, 
                                  T value) {

            List<T> ar3 = setOrAddDim3(indexDim1, indexDim2);

            int max = ar3.size();

            if (indexDim3 < 0)
                indexDim3 = 0;
            if (indexDim3 < max)
                ar3.set(indexDim3, value);

            for (int ix = max-1; ix < indexDim3; ix++ ) {
                ar3.add(value);
            }
        }



        private List<List<List<T>>> newArrayDim1() {
            List<T> ar3 = new ArrayList<>();
            List<List<T>> ar2 = new ArrayList<>();
            List<List<List<T>>> ar1 = new ArrayList<>();
            ar2.add(ar3);
            ar1.add(ar2);
            return ar1;
        }

        private List<List<T>> newArrayDim2() {
            List<T> ar3 = new ArrayList<>();
            List<List<T>> ar2 = new ArrayList<>();
            ar2.add(ar3);
            return ar2;
        }

        private List<T> newArrayDim3() {
            List<T> ar3 = new ArrayList<>();
            return ar3;
        }


        private List<List<T>> setOrAddDim2(int indexDim1) {

            List<List<T>> ar2 = null;

            int max = arrayList3D.size();
            if (indexDim1 < 0)
                indexDim1 = 0;
            if (indexDim1 < max)
                return arrayList3D.get(indexDim1);

            for (int ix = max-1; ix < indexDim1; ix++ ) {
                ar2 = newArrayDim2();
                arrayList3D.add(ar2);
            }
            return ar2;

        }

        private List<T> setOrAddDim3(int indexDim1, int indexDim2) {

            List<List<T>> ar2 = setOrAddDim2(indexDim1);
            List<T>       ar3 = null;

            int max = ar2.size();
            if (indexDim2 < 0)
                indexDim2 = 0;
            if (indexDim2 < max)
                return ar2.get(indexDim2);

            for (int ix = max-1; ix < indexDim2; ix++ ) {
                ar3 = newArrayDim3();
                ar2.add(ar3);
            }
            return ar3;
        }


        public List<List<List<T>>> getArrayList3D() {
            return arrayList3D;
        }

    }
```

And here is a test code:

```
        ArrayList3D<Integer> ar = new ArrayList3D<>();

        int max = 3;
        for (int i1 = 0; i1 < max; i1++) {
            for (int i2 = 0; i2 < max; i2++) {
                for (int i3 = 0; i3 < max; i3++) {
                    ar.setOrAddValue(i1, i2, i3, (i3 + 1) + (i2*max) + (i1*max*max));
                    int x = ar.get(i1, i2, i3);
                    System.out.println(" - " + i1 + ", " + i2 + ", " + i3 + " = " + x);
                }
            }
        }
```

Result output:

- 0, 0, 0 = 1
- 0, 0, 1 = 2
- 0, 0, 2 = 3
- 0, 1, 0 = 4
- 0, 1, 1 = 5
- 0, 1, 2 = 6
- 0, 2, 0 = 7
- 0, 2, 1 = 8
- 0, 2, 2 = 9
- 1, 0, 0 = 10
- 1, 0, 1 = 11
- 1, 0, 2 = 12
- 1, 1, 0 = 13
- 1, 1, 1 = 14
- 1, 1, 2 = 15
- 1, 2, 0 = 16
- 1, 2, 1 = 17
- 1, 2, 2 = 18
- 2, 0, 0 = 19
- 2, 0, 1 = 20
- 2, 0, 2 = 21
- 2, 1, 0 = 22
- 2, 1, 1 = 23
- 2, 1, 2 = 24
- 2, 2, 0 = 25
- 2, 2, 1 = 26
- 2, 2, 2 = 27

Answer (score 0):

You can also do something like this ...

- First create and Initialize the matrix or multidimensional arraylist

  `ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> list;
     MultidimentionalArrayList(int x,int y)
     {
         list = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i=0;i<=x;i++)
        {
          ArrayList<Integer> temp = new ArrayList<>(Collections.nCopies(y+1,0));
          list.add(temp);
        }
     }`

  - Add element at specific position 

    `void add(int row,int column,int val)
    {
     list.get(row).set(column,val); // list[row][column]=val
    }`

  > This static matrix can be change into dynamic if check that row and
  >   column are out of bound. just  insert extra temp arraylist for row

  - remove element

  `int remove(int row, int column)
      {
       return list.get(row).remove(column);// del list[row][column]
      }`

Answer (score 0):

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> C = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
        ArrayList<Integer> a = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        a.addAll(Arrays.asList(7, 3));
        ArrayList<Integer> b = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        b.addAll(Arrays.asList(2, 1));
        ArrayList<Integer> c = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        c.addAll(Arrays.asList(4, 9));
        C.addAll(Arrays.asList(a, b, c));

C.forEach(System.out::print);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<T>> multiDimentionalArray = new ArrayList<ArrayList<T>>();
```

You can change `T` to whatever data type you need