# Add predefined values to list of arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a List of ArrayList and would like to add predefined values to it using `addall`

```
List<ArrayList<String>> places;
```

But I'm not sure how to do so. Will it look something like the following:

```
places.addall(["a","b","c"],["aa","bb","cc"]....);
```

I tried that and it's not working.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [2 dimensional array list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10866205/2-dimensional-array-list)

Comment: You want a two dimensional list. See the link for various code samples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you can use addAll in that way, since addAll expects a `Collection` as the parameter; in your case it should be a `Collection<? extends List<String>>`

So, you need to create a Collection with the array looking data that you have and then add it to your `places` Collection.

The closest that i can think of is to do something as below,

```
    List<List<String>> places = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
    String[] string1 = new String[]{"a", "b", "c"};
    String[] string2 = new String[]{"aa", "bb", "cc"};
    places.add(Arrays.asList(string1));
    places.add(Arrays.asList(string2));
```

If you really want to use `addAll` then you'll have to do something like this,

```
    List<List<String>> tempPlaces = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
    String[] string1 = new String[]{"a", "b", "c"};
    String[] string2 = new String[]{"aa", "bb", "cc"};
    tempPlaces.add(Arrays.asList(string1));
    tempPlaces.add(Arrays.asList(string2));

    List<List<String>> places = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
    places.addAll(tempPlaces);
```

Comment: I think you should state that OP's confusion is that addAll expects a `Collection`, and that `Arrays.asList()` returns a `Collection`.

Comment: Correct, the contract is addAll(Collection<? extends E>)  
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#addAll(java.util.Collection)

Answer (score 1):

For your case first you add values to the ArrayList
     ArrayList al = new ArrayList();
        al.add("Hi");
        al.add("hello");
        al.add("String");
        al.add("Test");
    ArrayList al1 = new ArrayList();
        al1.add("aa");
        al1.add("bb");
        al1.add("cc");
        al1.add("dd");
Now you add these elements to your List

List> places;

places.add(al);
places.add(al1);