# Multi-dimensional Java ArrayList (Declared element syntax)

Tags: java, generics, multidimensional-array, arraylist

Is it possible to do the following?

```
private static ArrayList<integer<integer<String>>> myArrayList;
```

In other words, create an ArrayList with declared element syntax?

Example:

```
myArrayList[0][0] = "This is the string.";
```

If not, is it possible to do such with normal arrays?

Comment: Well have you tried it ? what results did you get ? and Integer will work much better than integer :)

Comment: Do you need a multi dimensional array of strings ?

Comment: `integer` should be `Integer` and also you cannot do `Integer<String>`. that's not allowed.

Comment: Is integer a user defined class? If not, your code won't even compile. Are you learning to program without writing programs?

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are looking for multi-dimensional arrays in Java, declared as follows:

```
String [][] list = new String[10][10];
list[0][0] = "This is a string";
System.out.println(list[0][0]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can declare `List` of `List` in the following way: -

```
List<List<String>> listOfList = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
```

Initialize your List, and then to add a String to your list element: -

```
listOfList.add(new ArrayList<String>());

listOfList.get(0).add("my String");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```
List<List<String>> list = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
list.add(new ArrayList<String>());

list.get(0).add("This is the string");
```

Answer (score 0):

What you would want to achieve in realtime?, Java defines set of APIs, which has its own usage and purpose. If you want to use multidimensional array, I would suggest to go for `Object[][]`, though you should be able to declare

```
ArrayList list[][] = new ArrayList[5][7];
```

By doing so, you would be making you operation bit complex. And more over `ArrayList` is nothing but single dimensional `Object` array.

FYI

[How to create a Multidimensional ArrayList in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4401850/how-to-create-multidemensional-arraylist-in-java)

Comment: You've got the wrong syntax there unfortunately. Not sure what you mean by "achieve in realtime" either.

Comment: I dont  understand by the comment 'wrong syntax', It is a valid java statement that can be compiled.

Comment: It does compile but I don't think it's doing what you meant. `new ArrayList[5][7]` will instantiate an array of arrays of raw `ArrayList`s, which isn't what the OP wants. You probably meant what Peter and Rohit demonstrate.

Comment: That doesn't mean the syntax is wrong,  agreed my answer is not that relevant OP's question.