# How to construct multidimensional ArrayLists?

Tags: java, arraylist

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to create multidemensional arraylist in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4401850/how-to-create-multidemensional-arraylist-in-java)

I have been having trouble understanding if and how an multidimensional Arraylist can be created. I know that from an ArrayList objects can be added,removed,checked, etc. and can be made two dimensionally, but can it be made 3 dimensionally.

- 2D `ArrayList<object1,object2,object3>`
- 3D `ArrayList<>`?

I know a regular array can be multidimensional simply by `int[][]` adding another set of brackets, but does an ArrayList work the same way?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "multidimensional"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>` is an ArrayList containing ArrayLists consisting of Integers, in other words, a 3d integer ArrayList.

Comment: Ah I see, but is there a way to create an ArrayList that will accept both strings and integers?

Answer (score 4):

I believe you should just be able to make an array list of array lists.

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>
```

for example, if you want a 2D array list of strings.

Or go in for a third:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>>
```

for a 3D array list.

Comment: Ah I see, but is there a way to create an ArrayList that will accept both strings and integers?

Comment: ArrayList<Object>, and cast down to String or the special integer class, Integer when you pull the object out of the array list.