# Java, add Value in 2 dimensional array of object

Tags: java, arrays

I have a little bit problem, about 2 Dimensional Array.

This is my example code:

```
Object data1[][] = {
        {icon.get(0), monster.get(0).getName(), monster.get(0).getAp(), monster.get(0).getHp(), monster.get(0).getDp(),},
        {icon.get(1), monster.get(1).getName(), monster.get(1).getAp(), monster.get(1).getHp(), monster.get(1).getDp(),},};
```

How to **convert** this adding values into a `for` loop?

- `monster` is an  `ArrayList` of Object `Monster`.
- `icon` is an `ArrayList` of Object `ImageIcon`.

Comment: You forgot to ask a question...

Comment: Haha, sorry for that.


the question is :

how can i convert that into loop for, so that i can assign the value without access manually.. :)

Comment: Your question looks like [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Can you tell us more about how are you going to use your array?

Comment: it's difficult to explain, plus more my bad english... :( 

I'll try:

I have 2 array List 
1. Array List of Monster
2. Array List of ImageIcon 

ImageIcon save the icon that the image's name retrieve from Monster

And i will save both Array ImageIcon and Monster into new 2 Dimensional array 


this 2 dimensional array , will be the data to Jtable 


*how about this, still confuse about my question.. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking for making an array based on numbers of monsters without hard-coding you need to do this

```
int numOfMonsters = monster.size();
Object data1[][] = new Object[numOfMonsters][5];
for(int i = 0; i < numOfMonsters; i++){
    data1[i][0] == icon.get(i);
    data1[i][1] == monster.get(i).getName();
    data1[i][2] == monster.get(i).getAp();
    data1[i][3] == monster.get(i).getHp();
    data1[i][4] == monster.get(i).getDp();    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Arrays are immutable in size, i.e. you cannot add a value to an array and increase it's size without creating a new array.

I would suggest using ArrayLists and then converting them with .toArray() if absolutely necessary.

Have a look at this question for an example:

[How to create a Multidimensional ArrayList in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4401850/how-to-create-a-multidimensional-arraylist-in-java)