# How do you create a Two-Dimensional ArrayList?

Tags: java

When I tried to declare this Two-D Array List,

```
    ArrayList<String>[][] names = new ArrayList<String>[][];
```

It gave me this Error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
>       Variable must provide either dimension expressions or an array initializer
>       Cannot create a generic array of ArrayList

```
at Prac5twodArraylistString.main(Prac5twodArraylistString.java:7)
```

Can you please help me understand the problem with this code?

Comment: read the errormessage and try to understand it. shouldn't be too hard

Comment: and OP's code is attempting to create not a 2D ArrayList, but a 2D array of ArrayList objects.

Comment: Look here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4401850/how-to-create-a-multidimensional-arraylist-in-java

Comment: Couldn't you use ArrayList<List<String>>?