# Print values of a 2D ArrayList Matrix

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a 2D Arraylist matrix like

```
    ArrayList[][] table = new ArrayList[10][10];
    table[0][0] = new ArrayList(); 
    table[0][1].add(10); 
    table[1][0].add(20); 
    table[1][1].add(30); 

    System.out.println("Value="+table[1][0].get()); //error line
```

The error occurs in the System.out.println line.
how do I print the values of the arraylist matrix??
can anyone suggest me a method??

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4401850/how-to-create-a-multidimensional-arraylist-in-java

Comment: You mean you don't get an error in `table[0][1].add(10)`? Considering that it has not been initialized, that would be strange.

Comment: @KumarSaurabh The declaration is correct. Only problem with `get()` method

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ Actually, Kumar may be on to the real problem here. It seems the OP thinks he has a 10x10 2D list of numbers, rather than a 10x10 array of lists of numbers (actually, raw lists...)

Comment: @RealSkeptic Nope. The indeces confusion. Added at one place and accessing another. Look at my answer.

Comment: @vineeth, which of [these two structures](http://i.imgur.com/Gs2nI7B.png) did you try to represent with your array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to think you have a 2-D matrix of numbers, stored as an `ArrayList`. That is not what you have at all. Instead, you have a 2-D matrix where each element is an `ArrayList`. That means you really have 3 dimensions represented in your code. I don't think that's what you want. There are several ways you could achieve two dimensions using the constructs you already have (i.e. without going to some external library).

## A 2-D array of numbers

The array is an easy to understand construct, so let's start with that.

```
Number[][] table = new Number[10][10];
table[0][0] = 0; 
table[0][1] = 10; 
table[1][0] = 20; 
table[1][1] = 30; 
System.out.println("Value="+table[1][0].get());
```

This code declares a 2-D array of type `Number`, then initializes it with 10 rows and 10 columns. It then partially fills in numbers. As long as you access an element that has already been initialized, you'll be ok. Trying to access an element that hasn't yet been initialized (like `table[3][4]`) would be bad.

### Another way to initialize an array

```
Number[][] table = { { 0, 10 }, { 20, 30 } };
System.out.println("Value=" + table[1][0]);
```

This is the same thing as before, but initialized all at once. This particular array only has 2 rows and 2 columns.

## Nested ArrayLists

If you want to use an `ArrayList` instead of an array, that's fine. You just need to realize that the `ArrayList` actually will contain other `ArrayLists`, each of which will contain `Numbers`. Like so:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Number>> table = new ArrayList<>();
table.add(new ArrayList<>());
table.add(new ArrayList<>());
table.get(0).add(0);
table.get(0).add(10);
table.get(1).add(20);
table.get(1).add(30);
System.out.println("Value=" + table.get(1).get(0));
```

In this example, you first declare an `ArrayList` that contains `ArrayLists` that contain `Numbers`, and initialize the outer `ArrayList`. Then you create some inner `ArrayLists`, and finally give each of them some `Numbers`.

## Summary

You can use arrays or `ArrayLists` as you prefer. You just have to initialize them correctly before accessing their elements. How to initialize depends on the data structure you choose.

## All the codes

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class TwoD {
  public void example1() {
    Number[][] table = new Number[10][10];
    table[0][0] = 0;
    table[0][1] = 10;
    table[1][0] = 20;
    table[1][1] = 30;

    System.out.println("\nExample 1");
    System.out.println("Value=" + table[1][0]);
  }

  public void example2() {
    Number[][] table = { { 0, 10 }, { 20, 30 } };

    System.out.println("\nExample 2");
    System.out.println("Value=" + table[1][0]);
  }

  public void example3() {
    ArrayList<ArrayList<Number>> table = new ArrayList<>();
    table.add(new ArrayList<>());
    table.add(new ArrayList<>());
    table.get(0).add(0);
    table.get(0).add(10);
    table.get(1).add(20);
    table.get(1).add(30);

    System.out.println("\nExample 3");
    System.out.println("Value=" + table.get(1).get(0));
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    TwoD me = new TwoD();
    me.example1();
    me.example2();
    me.example3();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

THe actual exception is at the lines

```
table[0][0] = new ArrayList(); 
  table[0][1].add(10);
```

You are adding element at 0,0 position and trying to add the arraylist element at 0,1.

Hence the nullpointer.

Try

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList[][] table = new ArrayList[10][10];
        table[0][0] = new ArrayList(); 
        table[0][0].add(10); 
        table[0][0].add(20); 
        table[0][0].add(30); 

        System.out.println("Value="+table[0][0].get(1)); 
    }
```

Comment: i tried using 1 and 0 but  i am getting null pointer exception. I dont know how to get the value from table[1][0]

Comment: @Suresh i tried using both indices and get(1).get(0) but it still gives null pointer exception

Comment: @vineethPrabhakaran Wait.. look the lines `table[0][0] = new ArrayList(); 
        table[0][0].add(10); ` and indeces. I changed your code and updated. Please run and see the difference.

Answer (score 1):

For using `ArrayList`, you must first declare the type of `ArrayList` in angular braces. Try using the code snippet as below:

```
    ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> table = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>(); //2d ArrayList
    ArrayList<Integer> x = new ArrayList<Integer>(); 
    x.add(10);
    x.add(20);
    table.add(x); 
    table.add(x); 

    System.out.println("Value="+table); //Prints table[][]
    System.out.println("Value="+table.get(0)); //Prints table[0]
    System.out.println("Value="+table.get(0).get(1)); //Prints table [0][1]
```

To insert a new row, you must do

```
table.add(new ArrayList<Integer>());
```

and to append another element on a specific row you must do

```
table.get(row).add(someValue);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for something more than toy project you should seriously consider using some external matrix library. Arrays will be painful in maintenance.

I could recommend [EJML](http://ejml.org/wiki/index.php?title=Main_Page). With usage of this library your code will look like this:

```
BlockMatrix64F matrix = new BlockMatrix64F(10, 10); 
matrix.set(0,1,10);
matrix.set(1,0,20);
matrix.set(1,1,30);

System.out.println("Value="+matrix.get(1,0));
```

Additionally it is quite likely that you will have to make some calculations inside your matrix. Library will have some support for basic ones, and will save you some time.