# How do I print a 2-dimensional integer array in Arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist, multidimensional-array

```
  List<int[][]> matrices = new ArrayList<>();
```

my arraylist is this. I wanna print all the elements in 2-d arrays which store into the arrayList. How can I do this ?

I tried some solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10477628/arraylist-of-int-array-in-java) but these are not working for me.

Comment: Have you tried something ? Show it here.

Comment: Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32376276/print-values-of-a-2d-arraylist-matrix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterate the list, and use `Arrays.deepToString` to print each element:

```
matrices.stream()
    .map(Arrays::deepToString)
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Or, for versions of Java which don't support streams:

```
for (int[][] matrix : matrices) {
  System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(matrix));
}
```