# Java Creating multiple arraylist

Tags: java, android, arraylist

The user will input a value between 1 and 5.
Base on the input value, I would like to create multiple arraylist with different names.

Example 1 (when input = 3) :

```
ArrayList<String> Group0 = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<String> Group1 = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<String> Group2 = new ArrayList<>();
```

Example 2 (when input = 5) :

```
ArrayList<String> Group0 = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<String> Group1 = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<String> Group2 = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<String> Group3 = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<String> Group4 = new ArrayList<>();
```

I apologise beforehand if this question seem trivial. I am relatively new to coding and thus would be very grateful to anyone who might know of an available method/command to get the above results. Thankyou!

---

I have tried to do it this way but i cant seem to use "label" when initialising arraylist. The error states "variable label is already defined in method main(String[]).

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int userInput = 3;
    int count = 0;

    while(count < (userInput)) {
        String label = "Group" + Integer.toString(count);
        ArrayList<String> label = new ArrayList<>();
        count++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Use a loop and store these lists in another list? What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: maybe this will help (create multi dimension arraylist).https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4401850/how-to-create-a-multidimensional-arraylist-in-java

Comment: @beatngu13 
I am trying to create an arraylist that correspond to a certain value that is not hardcoded. That value ranges from 1 to 5.
So, if the value is 2, i would like to automatically create group0 and group1. 
if the value is 4, i would like to automatically create group0, group1, group2. 

as u can see above, the names of the arraylist changes too when more arraylist are created.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a Multidimensional ArrayList in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4401850/how-to-create-a-multidimensional-arraylist-in-java)

Comment: @OferP Thankyou so much for the link! Yes it did help!! After reading that article, I have some ideas of how to code what Im looking for... Thankyou again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create a List of list and then with a for loop you can add your list to your general list.
for example :

```
List<List<String>> generalList = new ArrayList<>();
for(int i=0;i<input;i++)
{
 ArrayList<String> myGroup = new ArrayList<>();
 generalList.add(myGroup);
}
```

Comment: Okay, im giving this a try now... thankyou so much for such a prompt reply!

Comment: is it possible to have the name "myGroup" to automatically change after every for loop? 
maybe for example, when i=0, ArrayList is named "myGroup".
when i=1, ArrayList is named "myGroup1".
when i=2, ArrayList is named "myGroup2". 
etc etc

Comment: no it is not a common way.why you want something like this? you can create a class for your need, create a class that contains a String for name and a List of string

Comment: if you want to retrieve specific index in your list you can write this code : generalList.get(yourGroupIndex) for example you should write generalList.get(5) instead of "myGroup5"

Comment: Ah..... i get what your trying to say. Thankyou so much!!! I'll have to re-think of how i want to go about it and use .get() 
Thankyou so much!

Comment: your welcome buddy, let me know if it solved your problem.

Comment: I would like to apologise for the "noob" questions. Im not a programmer by education / profession. Just picking it up to learn and hopefully have it as a hobby... so pardon me for asking probably "stupid" questions.. :)

Comment: It's fine, it is not a stupid question and i will happy if i could help you :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use array of `ArrayList` for your requirement with given size by user input.

```
ArrayList<String> lists[]=new ArrayList[input];

for(int i=0;i<input;i++){
   lists[i]=new ArrayList<>();
}
```

Use `lists[0]` to access your first list and `lists[1]` for second and so on.

`ArrayList` is an option that provide dynamic arrays in Java, but that is not your requirement so use array also because `ArrayList` is slower than array.

---

Furthermore if your requirement is more specifically with name `Group1`, `Group2`..., You can use `HashMap` for the same.

```
HashMap<String,ArrayList<String>> maps=new HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>();

for (int i=0;i<input;i++)
     maps.put("Group"+String.valueOf(i),new ArrayList<String>());
```

When your want to retrieve arraylist from map use

```
maps.get("Group0");
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your question can be contrate into one simple thing: to create N ArrayList by N input by the user entered.

So you need a List object to store the N ArrayList objects;

So my code looks like :

```
import java.util.List;

import com.google.common.collect.Lists;

public class MultipleTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<List<String>> groupList = Lists.newArrayList();
        int input = 5;
        int N = input;
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            List<String> group_i = Lists.newArrayList();
            groupList.add(group_i);
        }
        System.out.println(groupList);
    }
}
```