# How to get 2d arraylist through loop?

Tags: java, object, arraylist

I am learning Java through self-reading. Right now I am doing a exercise. I am trying to create variable size of 2D-array then assign random number from 10 to 100 and put it into each array.

the problem I am encountering is don't know how to get each 2D-array out and put it into a string then show it through dialog after finish creating variable object.

here is my code.

```
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Random {
    public int randomNum;
    public String ID;

    public Random(String ID, int initialValue) {
        SecureRandom randomNumbers = new SecureRandom();
        this.ID = ID;
        this.randomNum = initialValue;
        int randomValue = randomNumbers.nextInt(99) + 1;
        randomNum = randomValue;
    }

    public int getRandomNum() {
        return randomNum;
    }

    public String getID() {
        return ID;
    }
}

class RandomText {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int ans = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("How many random number you want to show?"));

        ArrayList < Random > randomNum = new ArrayList < Random > ();
        for (int i = 0; i < ans; i++) {
            randomNum.add(new Random("ID " + Integer.toString(i), 0));
        }
        String result;
        for (int i = 0; i < ans; i++) {
            result = result + ?????? +"\n";
        }
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, result ")
    }
}
```

Comment: "_create variable size of 2D-array_" & "_how to get each 2D-array_" - There are no arrays in your code.

Comment: You do not have any 2 dimensional arrays?

Comment: Maybe it's my bad... I am trying to solve the ans and find that someone using Arraylist and Loop to creat object. I am trying to do so. Is it my way to do that is not right to solve the ans?

Comment: Actually I would like to do let say I want 5 number to show..
then...
ID1 10
ID2 20
ID3 35
ID4 14
ID5 22

Comment: "Solve the ans" is an expression I am not familiar with. Are you asking how to print a List? Or how to loop over the contents of a List?

Comment: I am trying to create 2D-array list which contains ID and RandomNum through loop and get all the ID and RandomNum out from the array

Comment: Well, you didn't create a 2D-ArrayList. You have a basic 1 dimensional arraylist of your custom "Random" class. A 2D-ArrayList would be one where every element of the outer ArrayList would be an ArrayList itself: `ArrayList<ArrayList<?>>`

Comment: Something similar to this requirement is [How to create a Multidimensional ArrayList in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4401850/how-to-create-a-multidimensional-arraylist-in-java) which contains examples.

Comment: Thanks for all you guys help first. Can anyone show me the link for "creating 2D-arraylist through loop"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing a couple of things to make this work.

1. Add a toString() method inside your Random class.  The toString() method in an object is used to change an object to a string representation of the local variables (In "Random" case, you want to return a string with the ID and the randomNum, see below code).
2. `String result;` needs to be assigned an initial value in order to use '+='.  Change it to `String result = "";`
3. Now that we have a "toString()" method, you can append it to result with `result = result + randomNum.get(i).toString();`

   ```
   import java.security.SecureRandom;
   import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
   import java.util.ArrayList;

   public class Random {
       public int randomNum;
       public String ID;

       public Random(String ID,int initialValue){
           SecureRandom randomNumbers = new SecureRandom();
           this.ID = ID;
           this.randomNum = initialValue;
           int randomValue = randomNumbers.nextInt(99)+1;
           randomNum = randomValue;
       }

       public int getRandomNum(){
           return randomNum;
       }

       public String getID(){
           return ID;
       }

       public String toString(){
           return ID + ": " + randomNum;
       }
   }

   class RandomText{
       public static void main(String[] args) {
           int ans = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog
                   ("How many random number you want to show?"));

           ArrayList<Random> randomNum = new ArrayList<Random>();
           for (int i = 0; i < ans; i++) {
               randomNum.add(new Random("ID " + Integer.toString(i),0));
           }
           String result = "";
           for (int i = 0; i < ans; i++) {
               result = result + randomNum.get(i).toString() + "\n";
           }
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, result);

       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks for your time to solve this question first! 
I will try best to understand every code you wrote here!

Answer (score 1):

I don't see why you need a 2D array when you can just use the `Random#getID` method you created:

```
String result;
for (Random random : randomNum) {
    result += random.getID() " : " + random.getRandomNum() + "\n";
}
```

But here is a method that uses a `Map` to create a 2D array list:

```
    Map<String, List<Integer>> idNums = new HashMap<String, List<Integer>>();
    randomNum.stream().forEach(r -> {
        if (idNums.get(r.getID()) != null) {
            idNums.get(r.getID()).add(r.getRandomNum());
        } else {
            idNums.put(r.getID(), Arrays.asList(r.getRandomNum()));
        }
    });

    ArrayList<List<Integer>> ids = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
    idNums.entrySet().forEach(e -> ids.add(e.getValue()));
```

Comment: Thanks for your help to write down how to make 2D-arraylist!

Comment: @Let'sYo answer updated.

Comment: Thanks for your help again!