# Is it possible to have a 2D array as member attribute but not initialized in constructor?

Tags: java, arrays, initialization, declaration

Problem is I have a text file I need to read that contains chars and I need to construct that into an 2D array internally in a class. But since when I initialize I also have to specify the values like so:

```
int[] array;
array = new int[] {2, 7, 9};
```

Since I don't know the size of the array before I read the file, I am able to create one as a member, but as a local one only. As of this, I resorted to using arrayLists, which is not desirable. Am I missing something?

Thanks.

Comment: an arraylist is designed specifically for this reason, when the total size of your collection is unknown. What's wrong with creating an arraylist of arraylists? it's equivalent to a 2D array but more flexible

Comment: wow, I did not know this. To answer your question, it's slow (not that it matters but it might) and I honestly find the syntax of a 2d arraylist more confusing than 2d arrays although it is more flexible as you say. That is basically it. @RAZ_Muh_Taz

Answer (score 2):

ArrayList would be the best option for this problem because the size of the `ArrayList` is mutable, meaning that no matter the size of the data, it will always change it's size to match the amount of elements it contains.

[Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4401850/how-to-create-a-multidimensional-arraylist-in-java) more detail on creating and using 2D ArrayLists.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

```
List<Integer> array = new ArrayList<>();

array.add(2);
array.add(7);
array.add(9);
```

OR prior to Java 9:

```
List<Integer> array = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(2,7,9));
array.add(10);
```

OR in Java 9:

```
List<Integer> array = List.of(2,7,9);
```