# How to create Multidimensional arraylist in Java dynamically?

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, arraylist

> ***I know there is a [similar question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4401850/how-to-create-a-multidimensional-arraylist-in-java)
>
> But the question I have here is different.***

My problem I have is about on how to create a Multi-dimensional ArrayList.
I know like for 2 dimensions I can do this

```java
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> dim2 = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
```

And I can keep on adding the dimensions like that. But for an array like that can be managable until 3 or 4 dimensions. (Readability will decrease if keep on doing that)

Is there any way or any class such that I can declare the dimensions of the ArrayList dynamically. I mean that the dimensions of the array should be declared at run time.
The above mentioned 2+ dimensional array is hard coded.

How can I achieve dynamic dimension declaration?

Comment: Why don't you start by writing the interface that you'd like your multidimensional array list to have -- the methods which get and set elements, and get the number of dimensions and the sizes of the array at particular points.

Comment: How would you expect to reference it?

Comment: @matt, I expect it to be like a list as it is in python. something very much similar like that

Comment: You could write a class that uses, .get(int... loc), and grab from your set of arraylists. I agree with tgdavies, you should make an interface you want. It might still be backed by ArrayList<ArrayList< .... > but you wouldn't have to write it out.

Comment: [What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378)

Answer (score 2):

You could try something like this:

```
int dims = 3;
ArrayList<Object> root = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<Object> current = root;
ArrayList<Object> previous = null;
for(int i = 0; i < dims; i++){
    previous = current;
    current=new ArrayList<Object>();
    previous.add(current);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would create a wrapper like a `LinkedList` with its next dimension as a member as well as the data:

```
public final class Dimension {

    private final List<Integer> data = new ArrayList<>();
    private final Dimension nextDimension;

    public Dimension(Dimension next) {
        this.nextDimension = next;
    }

    public static Dimension init(int depth) {
        Dimension d = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < depth; i++) {
            d = new Dimension(d);
        }
        return d;
    }
}
```

It is also possible to make `nextDimension` mutable if needed.