# Creating a new ArrayList in Java

Tags: java

Assuming that I have a class named `Class`,

And I would like to make a new ArrayList that it's values will be of type `Class`.

My question is that: How do I do that?

I can't understand from Java Api.

I tried this:

```
ArrayList<Class> myArray= new ArrayList ArrayList<Class>;
```

Comment: If you actually do have a class named Class, be aware that that could be easily confused with java.lang.Class - it won't confuse the compiler but it's likely to confuse anybody who comes along and reads your code.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

You are looking for Java generics

```
List<MyClass> list = new ArrayList<MyClass>();
```

Here's a tutorial http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html

Comment: That link to a tutorial PDF from Sun is broken.  This series of web pages from Oracle should be helpful: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html

Comment: Can also be shortened to `List<MyClass> list = new ArrayList<>();`, at least in Java 8.

Answer (score 17):

If you just want a list:

```
ArrayList<Class> myList = new ArrayList<Class>();
```

If you want an arraylist of a certain length (in this case size 10):

```
List<Class> myList = new ArrayList<Class>(10);
```

If you want to program against the interfaces (better for abstractions reasons):

```
List<Class> myList = new ArrayList<Class>();
```

Programming against interfaces is considered better because it's more abstract.
You can change your Arraylist with a different list implementation (like a LinkedList) and the rest of your application doesn't need any changes.

Answer (score 12):

You're very close. Use same type on both sides, and include `()`.

```
ArrayList<Class> myArray = new ArrayList<Class>();
```

Comment: I often see just "List" on the left side (like in the accepted answer). Why do you suggest ArrayList on both sides?

Comment: @KyleClegg mellamokb just took the code line from the question. If your question was about "List vs ArrayList", you can find some answers here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2279030/type-list-vs-type-arraylist-in-java

Answer (score 4):

You can use in Java 8

```
List<Class> myArray= new ArrayList<>();
```

Comment: What is the advantage of not writing Class in the <> of the right handside ?

Answer (score 3):

Do this: `List<Class> myArray= new ArrayList<Class>();`

Answer (score 3):

Fixed the code for you:

```
ArrayList<Class> myArray= new ArrayList<Class>();
```

Answer (score 3):

#### Java 8

In order to create a non-empty list of fixed size where different operations like add, remove, etc won't be supported:

```
List<Integer> fixesSizeList= Arrays.asList(1, 2);
```

Non-empty mutable list:

```
List<Integer> mutableList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(3, 4));
```

#### Java 9

With Java 9 you can use the `List.of(...)` static factory method:

```
List<Integer> immutableList = List.of(1, 2);

List<Integer> mutableList = new ArrayList<>(List.of(3, 4));
```

#### Java 10

With Java 10 you can use the [Local Variable Type Inference](https://developer.oracle.com/java/jdk-10-local-variable-type-inference.html):

```
var list1 = List.of(1, 2);

var list2 = new ArrayList<>(List.of(3, 4));

var list3 = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Check out more [ArrayList examples here](https://javatutorial.net/java-arraylist-example).

Answer (score 1):

```
    ArrayList<Class> myArray = new ArrayList<Class>();
```

Here ArrayList of the particular Class will be made. In general one can have any datatype like int,char,
string or even an array in place of Class.

These are added to the array list using

```
    myArray.add();
```

And the values are retrieved using

```
    myArray.get();
```

Answer (score 0):

[Material](http://leepoint.net/notes-java/data/collections/lists/arraylist.html) please go through this Link
 And also try this

```
 ArrayList<Class> myArray= new ArrayList<Class>();
```

Comment: *Never* use this! It is extremely bad practice to use concrete class at the left side of assignment when interface is available.

Comment: Not sure what's wrong, this looks like all the other answers. They must have edited?

Comment: @AlexR Nothing can prevent you from using the ArrayList class on the left type if you want to use ArrayList's specific methods (trimToSize, removeRange, ...) as the List interface doesn't contain these methods.