# Java inheritance question: What's the difference and why ? What advantages and flexibility does this give a programmer?

Tags: java, multithreading, inheritance

If I have a class called CountDownClock and it extends thread, and in another class I declare this:

```
Thread clock = new CountDownClock();
```

is that any different than:

```
CountDownClock clock = new CountDownClock();
```

if so what is the difference and pros/cons?
In the latter of the two declarations, can I still call parent methods?

Answer (score 4):

If the use of the `clock` variable relies only on the methods that `Thread` provides, than the former alternative is better, as it makes less assumptions about the particular object it refers to.

If the use of `clock` relies on `CountDownClock`-specific methods, then obviously the latter one is your only option.

The rule of thumb is basically to always choose the most general type possible when declaring a variable.

The same reason applies for preferring

```
List<String> someList = new ArrayList<String>();
```

over

```
ArrayList<String> someList = new ArrayList<String>();
```

> ***What's the difference and why?***

If the program compiles with any of the two alternatives, then technically there's no difference at all. The difference between the two is more related to maintenance. See below.

> ***What advantages and flexibility does this give a programmer?***

If `clock` is only used as a regular `Thread`, then choosing the first declaration makes it simpler to swap it for a different thread class in the future. (If it is declared as a `Thread` then you can be sure that it will compile fine for any other `Thread` class other than `CountDownClock`.)

**Related question:**

- [Type List vs type ArrayList in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2279030/type-list-vs-type-arraylist-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

The difference is only in type of containing variable. The memory referenced by both variables will have the same structure. You can always cast any variable to the other one (remember this is true when you store specialized class's object, not the parent's).

The pros/cons depends on your application design. Of course more abstraction is better, so using Thread instead of CountDownClock is preferred, But sometimes it is not possible and you have to use more specialized types(CountDownClock).