# Use interface instead classe when declaring some object

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Type List vs type ArrayList in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2279030/type-list-vs-type-arraylist-in-java)

I was studying Java language, and i saw some codes which when declaring some object, they used a interface as a base type but initialized with a complete class.

For instance:

```
    Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<String,String>();
```

So, what is the reason to use the interface Map instead the class HashMap on object declaration?

Answer (score 2):

The idea of using the interface is to allow the program to use any Map implementation. In principle you might want to replace the HashMap with -say- a TreeMap later and if the rest of the program only assumes that it is a Map then this replacement is trivial.

Answer (score 1):

If the programmer declared `map` as `HashMap` then the programmer may inadvertently use som `HashMap` specific methods or fields.  Then the programmer would be stuck with using a `HashMap`.

As it is, the programmer can easily change it from a `HashMap` to any other kind of `Map`.

Comment: I don't think there are any HashMap specific methods and I don't think there are any exposed fields either. The implementations of the collection interfaces mainly differ on their performance chararistics.

Answer (score 0):

You can't instantiate an interface. It's a contract that says "whatever class I use here will implement the methods declared in the interface". It's java's way of getting around the lack of multiple-inheritance.

@Mathias and @emory are correct as to the reason it's usually done this way with Map = new HashMap, whatever class creates the actual map used is free to implement it with a TreeMap, HashMap, BidiMap or whatever.