# Interview homework: Which is better Java ArrayList creation

Tags: java, list, arraylist

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Type List vs type ArrayList in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2279030/type-list-vs-type-arraylist-in-java)

Hi I have been asked the following question in an interview:

Which of the following would you choose recommended when and where?

```
ArrayList<SomeType> a = new ArrayList<SomeType>(); or
List<SomeType> a = new ArrayList<SomeType>();
```

I dont know much difference if anyone knows kindly please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Second is better cause you can simply change underlying implementation from `ArrayList` to `LinkedList` (or to any proper implementation) by one line code change.

Comment: Yes, unless you need to use any methods that are specific to `ArrayList`.

Comment: In summary, you should code deliberately. Use ArrayList because you are using ArrayList specific method(s) otherwise use the interface List.