# Passing an arraylist as argument to method

Tags: java, arraylist, arguments

I have a method which looks like this:

```
public Person(String name, Person mother, Person father, ArrayList<Person> children) {
    this.name=name;
    this.mother=mother;
    this.father=father;
    this.children=children;
}
```

When trying to create a new person with children, however, I run in to problems:

```
Person Toby = new Person("Toby", null, null, (Dick, Chester));
```

even though both Dick and Chester are defined further down. More specifically, it complains that neither Dick nor Chester can be resolved to a variable. Do I have to make a temporary ArrayList and pass that?

Thank you.

Comment: "_Do I have to make a temporary ArrayList and pass that?_" Yes. What you have right now is not valid Java code.

Comment: Consider List over ArrayList. For a comparison http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2279030/type-list-vs-type-arraylist-in-java.

Comment: You could then use the Array's `asList` method to pass around objects of same type.

Comment: @GauravAgarwal: `asList()` will only work if he changes his constructor to accept `List<Person>` instead of `ArrayList<Person>`

Comment: @GauravAgarwal: I fully agree. But it has to be mentioned, because using `Arrays.asList()` will only work if he chages it to `List<Person>`.

Comment: There is no such thing as 'defined further down' in Java. If you want to put an object into a Collection, it must be defined and instantiated beforehand. If it is not defined first, you will get a compiler error. If it is not instantiated, you are simply adding a  null object to your Collection.
(please consider using Java code conventions for declaring variables, i.e. lower-case first character.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you wouldn't pass `Dick` and `Chester` to the constructor like that.

You would, assuming you do have two Person objects named `Dick` and `Chester` :

```
ArrayList<Person> children = new ArrayList<Person>();
children.add(Dick);
children.add(Chester);

Person Toby = new Person("Toby", null, null, children);
```

You're constructor is expecting an ArrayList object so that is what you have to pass it. Notation like the one you used, `(Dick, Chester)`, doesn't make sense in Java.

Comment: This worked, but I had to make the ArrayList on the top of my code and add the children after they where initialized. Python was a lot simpler in this regard, at least it should be possible to do something like this:
Person Toby = new Person("Toby", null, null, ArrayList<Person>(Dick, Chester));

Comment: You can do it even in Java through `new ArrayList<Person>(Arrays.asList(new Person[]{Dick,Chester}))`, more verbose but semantically equivalent.

Comment: Honestly, even if you can do it, doesn't mean you should. Try and separate different operations in your code, don't do everything on one line. Readability is key.

Answer (score 3):

You can either use varargs:

```
public Person(String name, Person mother, Person father, Person... children) {
 ...
 this.children = Arrays.asList(children);
} 

Person p = new Person("Foo", Mother, Father, Dick, Chester);
```

Answer (score 1):

I would personally change the Person constructor to be:

```
public Person(String name, Person mother, Person father, Person... children)
{
}
```

The ... basically means the constructor will create its own array of Person objects so a call to it would be, for example:

```
Person toby = new Person("Toby", null, null, childOne, childTwo, childThree);
```

Or:

```
Person toby = new Person("Toby", null, null);
```

Comment: This won't work unless he changes Person's constructor to accept List instead of ArrayList.

Comment: Secondly, Dick and Chester are Person instances, not strings.

Comment: This would only work if he changes his constructor to accept `List<Person>` instead of `ArrayList<Person>`. Also, you can just write `Arrays.asList(childOne, childTwo)`, because it's a varargs method, so you don't have to create the array manually.

Comment: Well then you just change the constructor. It's his code, and not 3rd party.

Comment: @Amorgos: Yes, but you have to mention it in your answer!

Answer (score 0):

Your example doesn't look like a Java code.
First of all you have to define Dick and Chester before using them. So they have to be created "above" Toby.
Secondly, round brackets don't create you a list. You have to explicitly create an array list with this:

```
new ArrayList<Person>()
```

Answer (score 0):

Incase you were not able to follow the comments on the question try this:

```
public Person(String name, Person mother, Person father, List<Person> children) {
    this.name=name;
    this.mother=mother;
    this.father=father;
    this.children=children;
}
```

Here I have changed the signature to take the last parameter as List type.

```
Person Toby = new Person("Toby", null, null, Arrays.asList(Dick, Chester));
```

Also the children signature would have to be changed.
The point here is to use a more abstract type.