# Getting "not generic" error when attempting to use List<> In Java

Tags: java, list, arraylist

Here is my code:

```
class mynode
{
   mynode prev;
   mynode next;
       int value; 
}

class link
{
   List<mynode> pos;
   link(int x)
   {
       pos = new ArrayList<mynode>();
   }
}
```

I have seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2279030/type-list-vs-type-arraylist-in-java) that using List is better than using ArrayList. So why am I seeing below error?

```
The type List is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments <mynode>
```

Comment: Are you using `java.util.List`?

Comment: I guess you have wrong import.

Comment: Most likely you are importing something else than `java.util.List`

Comment: Are you sure you're importing `java.util.List`?  Or are you accidentally using `java.awt.List`?

Comment: Oh I was using java.awt.List

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your code looks fine so I guess you made mistake in import section. Common mistake when you start using IDE like Eclipse is choosing `java.awt.List` instead of `java.util.List` from import suggestions. List you want to use comes from `java.util` package.