# Build an ArrayList<> from a List<>

Tags: java, list, arraylist

What is the best way of building an `ArrayList<>` from a `List<>` ?

An Example would be great

and another question, should i keep working with a `List<>` instead of converting all my `Lists` to `ArrayLists`

**Edit**

Just to be sure of my code : can this work :

```
public List<Rendezvous> getAllNewlyDoneRdvs() {
        if (!isThereNewlyDoneRdvs())return null;
        List<Rendezvous> rdvs = rdvDao.findAllByState(Constants.rdvStateUndone);
        ArrayList<Rendezvous> rendezvousList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Rendezvous rdv :rdvs ){
            if (rdv.getDateRdv().before(Constants.getCurrentDatetime())) rendezvousList.add(rdv) ;
        }
        rdvs = rendezvousList;
        return rdvs;
    }
```

Comment: Check out this question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2279030/type-list-vs-type-arraylist-in-java

Comment: It depends on what you do with your `List`. If you just access it by e.g. iterating over it, the basic class `List` should be sufficient.

Comment: Related: [what-does-it-mean-to-program-to-an-interface](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/383947/what-does-it-mean-to-program-to-an-interface)

Comment: Note that an ArrayList is a List.

Comment: And since a List is a Collection, you can use `new ArrayList<>(someList)` to create a copy of a List as an ArrayList.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

assumming both of the type are same

`List<>` could be already an `ArrayList<>` in that case just change reference
if not iterate and add

Comment: Ah so then i can build an `ArrayList<>` , fill it and then in the end make a `List<>` refernce and affect my arraylist to it and return it ?(since my methods return `List<>`)

Comment: yes `List` is an interface, it could be `ArrayList`

Comment: I prefer Collection<> collection = new ArrayList<>(); Because the collections gives you a broader option of set and trees.

Comment: @JigarJoshi is my code (in the edit) is correct, just to make sure

Answer (score 3):

If you want to be sure that you have an ArrayList to work with, you can just do `new ArrayList(existingList)`.

The best reason for doing this might be that you want to add, update, or remove items from the list without affecting the original list.

Answer (score 1):

It will be good practice using List while declaring.

```
List<> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

Answer (score 1):

You should know that List is an Interfaces and ArrayList is a concrete class, so you should always use

```
List<Type> myList = new ArrayList<Type>();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use Collections.list() as illustrated [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/collections_list.htm)

Answer (score 0):

You can get caught out if you have a method taking a `List` parameter because some implementations of `List` (even in the standard library) are immutable or are of a fixed size.
In which case, if you need a mutable list, it's completely reasonable to create an `ArrayList` with the same contents as your existing uncertain-implementation `List`

```
ArrayList<T> newArrayList = new ArrayList<T>(oldList);
```

Answer (score 0):

It sheems you are comparing the dates first and then preparing the new list.

This is absolutely fine.  But in this case you should have another method in DAO itself which returns the List of Rendezvous having DateRdv before current date.

Comment: well, that's not the approach i opted for, i search List<Rendezvous> with their state(done or not done yet, i need that for the purpose of my app ;) )