# Java - Can we declare object variable in constructor?

Tags: java, constructor

While creating an object, can we declare and initialize object variable in `constructor`?

I am creating an object based on XML. XML format is output of previous system and is dynamic.

Hence object variable is based on elements. it will be better if I declare variable in constructor.

In the below code can we declare temp as object variable.

For example:

```
public class A
{
    public A()
    {
        HashMap<String, Object> temp = new HashMap<String, Object>;
    }
}
```

I could not find any sample code for this ideology.
Any suggestions?

Comment: If you declare variable in body or constructor or in {} then it is visible only in that scope.
If you want to create object/class member you have to declare it in class scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for something a bit different.

```
public class A {
   // Constructor
   private A() {
   }

   public static A createObjectA(...) {
      A result = new A();
      // In here transform the XML in a suitable format and set it into the result object.
      // Return the result
      return result;
   }
}
```

Let's examine the code above. You have a constructor that can be invoked just within the class, so you're sure nobody will use it in a bad manner.

Then you have a static function that provides you an instance of Object A, you'll create every instance of A through this via:

```
A newObj = A.createObjectA(...);
```

You can add as many static functions to allocate the object matching the number of various input formats you have, the advantage of this approach is that your resulting object will be free of the logic to parse previous input.

Ofc you can put the static function inside another class, but then you'll have to make the constructor callable (what you usually do with friend functions in C++).

Comment: Thank you Mike, implementing this approach.

Answer (score 2):

You can declare variable inside constructor but it scope would be limited to that constructor.Instead you can do

```
public class A
{
   HashMap<String, Object> temp;
    public A()
    {
         temp = new HashMap<String, Object>;
    }
}
```

declare it outside the constructor and initialize it inside constructor by this it can be accessible in any methods of class because its scope is global now.

Answer (score 1):

If you declare it inside the constructor, it will be local to the constructor, which means it won't be very useful. You can do it, however, if this variable only needs to be used inside the constructor.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can.

But scope of visibility will be only at constructor.

You can access `temp` only into constructor (only from `{` till `}`) :

```
public class A { 

  public A() {
      Map<String, Object> temp = new HashMap<String, Object>;        
  } // end scope of visibility for `temp`
```

It wouldn't the best solution if you want to use this map later (for objects, etc).

But if you need to use it only at constructor it is fine.

If you will use this map outside of the constructor:

```
public class A {

  Map<String, Object> temp;

  public A() {
      temp = new HashMap<String, Object>;        
  }
  // you can use it here
```

***BTW***
Good practice is use interface reference:

> Map temp = new HashMap;

instead of:

> HashMap temp = new HashMap;

More info here: [Type List vs type ArrayList in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2279030/type-list-vs-type-arraylist-in-java/18356563#18356563)

Answer (score 0):

Constructors act like any other block of code (e.g., a method or an anonymous block). You can declare any variable you want there, but it's scope will be limited to the constructor itself.

It sounds as though you need to declare some collection or map as a data member and have the constructor fill its values dynamically.