# Why is declaring List implementation not needed?

Tags: java, list, interface, spotify

I am using a method that returns type `List<>`, and I am then able to call methods on that `List` :

```
List<Artist> artists = artistsPager.artists.items;
artists.add(new Artist());
```

To be clear `artistsPager.artists.items` is returning type `List<Artist>`.

Since `List` is only an interface, how is the compiler letting me use this `artists` object, doesn't a `List<>` always need an implementation, like `ArrayList`?

For example, the compiler won't let me do the following, because "List is abstract; cannot be instantiated":

```
List<Integer> list = new List<Integer>();
```

How is `artistsPager.artists.items` any different than `new List<Integer>()`?

For those curious, this come from the [Java Web API wrapper for Android](https://github.com/kaaes/spotify-web-api-android). All help is greatly appreciated.

I do not believe this is a duplicate of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2279030/type-list-vs-type-arraylist-in-java) because even though the answers are the same, the question that begets them is different. The other question is asking the difference between type `List` and `ArrayList`, whereas my question was wondering why the compiler was not complaining when the implementation of `List` was hidden.

I am fine with having this marked as a duplicate to direct future users to that question, but I do not think it should be closed as the answers here I think would be immensely helpful to other users.

Comment: You should look up interfaces/abstract classes and see how they're used in Java. It's an important set of knowledge to have, especially when dealing with high profile libraries like Android and the JDK, since Interfaces are used almost everywhere in them.

Comment: Thanks @DaveLugg, I was confused because I looked through the source code of the Spotify API and could not find any instantiation of it as anything other than type List. Next time I will trust the compiler! Is there any quick way to figure out where the List<> is actually implemented, rather than traversing the code?

Comment: The point of using the interfaces is that you shouldn't care where it's implemented, just that it's a `List`. The `ArrayList` type is an implementation of it, and is probably the most common. So you could use `List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();`.

You can find default implementations of List interface in oracle docs (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html) and see "All known implementing classes"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How is artistsPager.artists.items any different than `new List<Integer>()`?

`artistsPager.artists.items` is a field of type `List<>`. Somewhere in the code, it must have been instantiated with a concrete implementation like `ArrayList`.

`new List<Integer>()` is a constructor call, which is invalid because `List` is an interface.

Comment: Got it, I guess I was confused because I didn't see the concrete implementation of of type List<>.

Answer (score 2):

> doesn't a `List<>` always need an implementation, like `ArrayList<>`?

Yes, you need an implementation in order to create an instance. However, the compiler knows two things:

- It knows that you have already created *some* instance, and assigned it to `items`, and
- It knows that whatever you have assigned to `items`, implements `List<>` interface

Knowing these two things is enough for the compiler to let you call `add` on a variable declared as an interface type. In this way *your* code does not need to care what implementation you get - an `ArrayList<>`, a `LinkedList<>`, or some custom implementation you developed: your code will work with all of them.

Note that the practice of referring to objects through their interface type is desirable. It is called *programming to interface*. It lets you hide implementation details, and swap objects for different implementations later on.

Answer (score 0):

This means that a concrete list was created somewhere (for example, an `ArrayList`).

You only know that the list that is created is implementing methods from the `List` interface, allowing you to use these methods.

Take this example hiding the concrete `LinkedList` from the user:

```
public static List<Integer> makeListOfInts(){
    return new LinkedList<Integer>(){
        {
            add(1);
            add(2);
        }
    }
}
```

I can be easily replaced with an `ArrayList`:

```
public static List<Integer> makeListOfInts(){
    return new ArrayList<Integer>(){
        {
            add(1);
            add(2);
        }
    }
}
```

And all the function's user knows is that a `List` is returned, but it does not know the concrete type of the list. It may only use functions from the `List` interface, and not from the specific implementation that was selected.