# What is the difference between these declarations of an ArrayList?

Tags: java, list, arraylist

This is more of a best practice question, I think.

I often see ArrayLists being declared like this:

```
ArrayList<T> array = new ArrayList<T>();
```

Yet I've been taught that I should declare an ArrayList like the following:

```
List<T> array = new ArrayList<T>();
```

In terms of compiling or execution, I've never noticed any different between the two... What is the best practice when declaring ArrayLists? As far as I understand, it would be best to use the least specific declaration which would be using List.

Comment: the first cannot be used by methods that can cope with any type of list

Comment: If you need any specific methods of the subtype, use the subtype, otherwise be as general as possible.

Comment: Google "program to an interface" to know what are the uses of using `List<T> array = new ArrayList<T>();`

Comment: `List<T>` is a interface

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2279030/type-list-vs-type-arraylist-in-java

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! It seems my question has been already discussed and answered elsewhere so I apologise for not searching thoroughly before posting my question.