# Shifting the contents of the `ArrayList` to the right

Tags: java, arraylist

I've written a code which shifts the contents of the `ArrayList` to the right and the shifting can be any number passed to the method 
`shiftRight(String myString, int shift)`
Inside the method, I need to put every `char` of a passed `String` into the `ArrayList myList`.

For example, if I have

```
"abcdef", 2
```

the result should be

```
efabcd
```

as it shifts `2` letters to the right.
Another example:

```
"abcdef", 4
```

then the output is

```
cdefab
```

My code gives `edabcf` when the shift is `2` and the `String` is `"abcdef"` whereas it should produce `efabcd`. Coulb smb please help me out? I tried to debug it but still could not figure out why it's taking `d` instead of `f`. Thanks in advance!

---

**Logic of the code:**

1)Put every character inside the `ArrayList myList` by running a `for - loop`

2)I assigned the value of `shift` to a temporary `count` which decrements inside the `while-loop`. Inside the `while-loop` I added the character, which would be removed soon, to the `ArrayList temp` from the `myList`(if the `shift` is `2`, then the characters `ef` are added to the `temp`). Remove those characters from `myList` afterwards inside the same loop.

3)Added characters from `temp` list to the `myList`

---

```
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class ShiftToTheRight {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        String myString = "abcdef";
        int shift = 2;
        ArrayList<String> myList = shiftRight(myString, shift);
        for(int i = 0; i < myList.size(); i++){
            System.out.print(myList.get(i) + "");
        }
    }

    public static ArrayList<String> shiftRight(String myString, int shift){

        ArrayList<String> myList = new ArrayList<>();

        //Put every character inside the myList
        for(int i = 0; i < myString.length(); i++){
            myList.add(myString.charAt(i) + "");
        }

        ArrayList<String> temp = new ArrayList<>();

        //Add the rightmost characters into the temp
        //Delete those characters from the myList
        int count = shift;
        while(count != 0){
            temp.add(myList.get(myList.size() - shift));
            myList.remove(myList.get(myList.size() - shift));
            count--;
        }

        //Add the characters from the temp to the beginning of the myList
        for(int i = 0; i < temp.size(); i++){
            myList.add(i ,temp.get(i));
        }


        return myList;
    }
}
```

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis, done. Take a look into the description.

Comment: Must you return an array list of strings from the method? Can you return a shifted string?

Comment: I have to return a `shifted string` inside the `arraylist` (I've been challenging myself :) ), @andrewdleach

Answer (score 0):

It is not required to use a List-class for that simple string-operations.
it can be done using substring:

```
private static String shift(String input, int count){
    if(count >= input.length())
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("count should be smaller than input.length");

    int start = input.length()-count;
    String part1 = input.substring(start);
    return part1 + input.substring(0, start);
}

public static void main(String[]  args){
    System.out.println(shift("abcdef", 2));
    System.out.println(shift("abcdef", 4));
}
```

Output is:

```
efabcd
cdefab
```

Comment: Thanks and sorry but I already know how to do using String. I'd like to also do this problem using Arraylists! @ChrisKo

Comment: well if you are just curious its ok but i would never accept such a overhead-solution for a real-application. ;)

Comment: Wow, i got 4 Downvotes for absolutely no reason. Thanks for your fairness, guys.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of mutating a list, this problem would be easier to solve using an array. An ArrayList has an array as a backing store but it obfuscates the issue at hand which is manipulating the char indices.

Try this instead:

```
public static String shiftRight(final String theString, final int theShift){

    char[] string = theString.toCharArray();
    char[] temp = string.clone();

    int indexRun = 0;
    for (int i = theShift; i < string.length; i++) {
        temp[i] = string[indexRun];
        indexRun++;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < theShift; i++) {
        temp[i] = string[indexRun];
        indexRun++;
    }

    return new String(temp);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As jdevelop's answer states, the best way to do this is to implement a simple method that operates on the ArrayList.

As I cannot add a picture to my comments without simply providing a link, I'm posting this answer in support of his.

[image]

In the first step of his code, a copy of the last element (the pink oval) is copied for later. All elements are shifted to the right.

Then the pink element is reintroduced using the set(int index, T t) method on lists.

The method you would incorporate to do this multiple times would look similar to this, including his original code:

```
void shiftArrayXTimes(List<T> l,int x){
    while(int i = 0; i < x; i++){
        shiftRight(l);
}
}
```

In an arraylist, this is not much different. It is also generally preferred to use a [List over an ArrayList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2279030/type-list-vs-type-arraylist-in-java), though this is subjective.

Comment: If you upvote my answer, please upvote jdevelop's answer as his answer is correct. I simply explain an underlying concept visually.

Comment: hehe, I've got even some downwote over there ;)

Answer (score -1):

Instead of `myList.size() - shift` do `myList.size() - 1`. You wanna grab the last char. Same with the remove. And when putting together the chars, you  wanna do `myList.add(0, temp.get(i)` so it always adds the chars to the beginning of the list. Otherwise, your code seems functional

Answer (score -2):

What you have to do for the shift is to simply add the single function that takes the single value from the end of the list, and moves things one step to the right.

```
public static <T> void shiftRight(List<T> lst) {
    if (lst == null || lst.isEmpty()) {
        return;
    }
    T t = lst.get(lst.size() - 1);
    // list index is zero-based
    for (int i = lst.size() - 2; i >= 0; i--) {
        lst.set(i + 1, lst.get(i));
    }
    lst.set(0, t);
}
```

Hence you're doing shift by 1 item to the right, and you use O(1) of the additional memory to keep the new list.

now if you need to shift by 2 items - invoke the function twice.

Comment: why is there `i + i`. Secondly, why is there `set(0, t);`, @jdevelop.

Comment: @John i+i is a typo, and set(0,t) - you need to set the first item of the list to the value of the last item in the list after you have shifted all the items by one position to the right

Comment: Everything shifts to the right one place. The object on the far right of the array shifts to the beginning of the array. That is why the set(0, t); is called - to place the last indice at the front.