# Java Mahjong Game - Help Implementing a hand reorganizing that shifts JLabels away from where I drag my chosen piece

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, drag

I'm currently making a java Mahjong game, and I'm working on the GUI. I have a JPanel which holds an array of JLabels each with a custom mouse listener.

What I would like is to implement some way of reorganizing your hand. For example, you just drew a tile, and you want to put it in the far left to keep some organization in your hand.

I already can drag tiles, but I would like it to **snap into place** when you release it and then **shift every other tile down**. So if I put it in the far left, every tile moves one right. So the program would need some way of **recognizing that a tile has been moved, and determining what position it is in.** I would appreciate some guidance on how to implement this, or what I would need to change/add/research.

Here is my mouse listener class, let me know if any other information is needed.

```
package mahjongCode;

import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Cursor;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class DragAndDropListener extends MouseAdapter{
    private Point startPoint;
    private Component draggedObject;
    private JPanel panel;
    private JLabel[] handTiles;

    public DragAndDropListener(JPanel panel, JLabel[] handTiles){
        this.panel = panel;
        this.handTiles = handTiles;
    }
    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e){
        panel.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
        draggedObject = (Component) e.getSource();
        startPoint = SwingUtilities.convertPoint(draggedObject, e.getPoint(), 
                                                    draggedObject.getParent());
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e){
        Point location = SwingUtilities.convertPoint(draggedObject, e.getPoint(), 
                                                        draggedObject.getParent());
        Point locTrans = location.getLocation();
        locTrans.translate(draggedObject.getParent().getX(), draggedObject.getParent().getY());
        if(draggedObject.getParent().getBounds().contains(locTrans)){
            Point newLocation = draggedObject.getLocation();
            newLocation.translate(location.x - startPoint.x, location.y - startPoint.y);
            newLocation.x = Math.max(newLocation.x, 0);
            newLocation.x = Math.min(newLocation.x, draggedObject.getParent().getWidth() - draggedObject.getWidth());
            newLocation.y = Math.max(newLocation.y, 0);
            newLocation.y = Math.min(newLocation.y, draggedObject.getParent().getHeight() - draggedObject.getHeight());
            draggedObject.setLocation(newLocation);
            panel.repaint();
            startPoint = location;
        }
    }

    @Override 
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e){
        panel.setCursor(null);
        startPoint = null;
        draggedObject = null;
    }

    public void makeDraggable(Component component){
        component.addMouseListener(this);
        component.addMouseMotionListener(this);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have an Array of JLabels, you're already halfway through your solution! I actually answered a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31976100/shifting-the-contents-of-the-arraylist-to-the-right/31976614#31976614) just recently.

You may find it to be beneficial.

As for 'snapping into place' if you're drawing the hand of tiles based on array indice, the snapping is done for you, as they will be drawn in place after snapping.

I don't know much about Mahjong, though I assume the tiles are similar to cards in a hand of Uno in as much that you are not limited to a set value. If this is the case, an ArrayList may be extremely beneficial. You can read some opinons on [ArrayList vs Array here](http://www.quora.com/What-are-the-advantages-to-using-the-ArrayList-class-rather-than-a-regular-array).

---

### Edit:

[image]

I see that there are a few ways you can go about this, there may be more:
If each tile gains a relative portion of the frame/screen/pane, then you can get the value of it's x coordinate(red line on tile), and as you drag your mouse (blue arrow, red dot point) towards the left, past the green arrow, automatically shift that tile left one.

If there is a maximum amount of tiles, such as 4, in this example, as your mouse moves past a fixed width, you can directly exchange the tiles based on that predetermined value.

Perhaps the easiest method I can see for doing this is:

[image]

Getting the coordinates of the last known position of the mouse when they release their drag and drop (I'm assuming it's click and drag), and then systematically comparing positions with each index until you get a position and then dealing with it that way.

Since the X value in this example is smaller than all others, it's placed at the front of the arraylist. The arraylist positions determine where each tile is drawn. When you release your mouse here,  selected tile is saved in a local variable, then all tiles are shifted to the right one slot to accommodate the new change, and finally, the selected tile position is set to (150,100), based on array index 0.

Comment: Awesome, thanks, although I'm wondering how I should go about figuring out where to place the tile? I can visually drop the tile in place, but how does the program know that I put it in spot 1 versus spot 6? And yes the tiles are treated just as you would with uno cards.

Comment: Well, for instance, lets say tiles are each 50 pixels wide. Test that the mouse location is > or < 50% of the tiles absolute position, plus the 50% of the width. Picture and updated answer incoming.

Comment: Wow this is really great. Thank you so much!

Comment: The program knows you put it in slot 1 through a function that determines it, based on either an X coordinate, or boolean value. Roughly speaking, you're either going to direct your code to 'place tile in buffer slot, move all tiles down one, place buffer tile into slot 0' or you'll direct your code to 'swap these two tiles'

Either way does what you're asking, however, one is more efficient and requires less calls.