# Java: Create a list of a class (List<Class>), and iterate through it

Tags: java, data-structures

I'm coming from a C# background, and I'm trying to figure out how to use classes the way I used them in C#. If this is *not* the way to use them in Java, I'd like to know the *correct* way to do it.

Basically, here's what I want to do:

1. **Create a List and fill it with data.**
2. **Iterate through said List**

Here's my attempt thus far:

1. **The is the class object I want**:

   ```
   public class ClassName
   {
       public ClassName(String _str, int _a, int _b, int _c, int _d, long _e)
       {
           str = _str;
           a = _a;
           b = _b;
           c = _c;
           d = _d;
           e = _e;
       }
       public String str;
       public int a;
       public int b;
       public int c;
       public int d;
       public long e;
   }
   ```
2. **This is the way it's referenced in the main class file:**

   ```
   // Why would I use this instead of List<T>?
   ArrayList<ClassName> hList = new ArrayList<ClassName>();
   ```
3. **This is how I'm attempting to fill the class object:**

   ```
   hList.add(new ClassName("string", 1, 2, 3, 4, 2432342322));
   ```

**This is the error I'm getting in Eclipse**:

`The constructor ClassName(String, int, int, int, int, long) is undefined`

...which is baffling. Eclipse asks me to add what I've *already* added. When I choose the "quick fix" option, it does the same thing as the constructor above, but without the `type = type` stuff. Maybe I'm not handling this correctly?

Assuming this is the right way to iterate, here's what I'd assume would work:

```
for (int i = 0; i < hList.size(); i++)
{
    System.out.println(hList[i].currentDate);
}
```

So, how do I create a proper list and iterate through it in Java?

Comment: You're passing 4 ints and your constructor takes 3 int parameters

Comment: As a side note, `ArrayList<ClassName> hList = new ArrayList<ClassName>();` would usually be done as `List<ClassName> hList = new ArrayList<>();`. That keeps your code more flexible, since you aren't tied to a specific implementation of `List`.

Comment: Sorry, let me update it. The constructor/parameter-passing is correct in the IDE.

Comment: With typos fixed (string -> String, 2432342322 -> 2432342322L, etc.) your updated code compiles cleanly for me.  I doesn't seem like you're trying to compile what you're saying you're trying to compile.  Instead of manually typing in what you think your code says, why not copy-paste that **exact** code which is giving you an error?  See [how to make an mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: To add to @resueman's comment. `List` is the parent of `ArrayList` -- this is polymorphism in the sense that any operation you do on `List` works on `ArrayList` so you end up being more flexible.

Comment: @resueman there are counter arguments. Not all implementations of `List` have a working `add` (`Arrays.asList` returns a `List` that you can't `add` to). Plus having declared `someList` to be an `ArrayList` will never restrict you. More generic is good for arguments of public interfaces only. Best accept any `List`, or any `Collection` as a parameter to leave more flexibility on the user. Return a specific implementation `ArrayList` rather than `List` gives more information. And, more importantly, the returned value can be used in methods that explicitly require an ArrayList.

Comment: @bourbaki4481472 the problem with that is that all useful methods in `List` are optional (`add` and `remove` and similar).

Comment: @njzk2 There's an argument to be made both ways, but the [general consensus](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2279030/type-list-vs-type-arraylist-in-java) I've seen has been that `List` is usually preferred. Personally, I feel that the habit of keeping code generic when it's reasonable to do so outweighs the benefits of restricting more than you need.

Comment: @njzk2 I disagree. Returning `List` is better than returning `ArrayList`. It keeps the API generic and lets you change the concrete type of list being returned without affecting callers. It should be clear from context whether the `List` is read-only or writable, and if not, the API documentation should specify it. That's how optional methods should be handled, not by avoiding `Collection` and `List`.

Comment: @JohnKugelman, why would I do `List<ClassName> list = new ArrayList<>();` instead of `List<ClassName> list = new List<>();` (which obviously doesn't work)? Am I missing something here?

Comment: @JohnKugelman When you return an ArrayList, you provide information: *What is the cost of adding/inserting/removing items? Is it even supported? How big can that list grow?*... And you allow your caller to use it in contexts where only ArrayList is accepted. Using more restricting types, you say *I may change my mind about what I want you to do with this data. You (whatever doing) algorithm on this list has unknown complexity because I may change my mind at any point*. (I think this is mostly because the `List` interface is flawed, though).

Comment: @njzk2 Your last parenthetical might be the underlying reason we do things differently: `List` is flawed. I agree with you there. It *should* guarantee O(1) random access and `LinkedList` *should* extend `Collection`, not `List`. In my mind, that's the way things are. I consider a non-O(1) `get()` method to be broken. Therefore, I return `List` when I want to allow callers to lookup items by index without worrying about speed. That way I can switch from `ArrayList` to `Arrays.asList()` to Guava's `ImmutableList` freely. I think this policy works because nobody I know ever uses `LinkedList`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

#### I

```
public ClassName(string _str, int _a, int _b, int _c, long _d)
{
    str = _str;
    a = _a;
    b = _b;
    c = _c;
    d = _d;
}
```

Naming with underscores isn't so common. I recommend using `this` instead. Also, `String` is capitalized, and curly braces are typically at the end of lines.

```
public ClassName(String str, int a, int b, int c, long d) {
    this.str = str;
    this.a = a;
    this.b = b;
    this.c = c;
    this.d = d;
}
```

#### II

```
// Why would I use this instead of List<T>?
ArrayList<ClassName> hList = new ArrayList<ClassName>();
```

A more generic type like `List`, `Collection`, or `Iterable` is better on the lefthand side, same as in C#. I recommend against Hungarian notation: `list` is preferred over `hList`. Additionally, you can omit the right side type name and use the [diamond operator](http://tamanmohamed.blogspot.com/2012/05/jdk7-using-diamond-operator-for.html) (`<>`) to infer the type.

```
List<ClassName> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

#### III

> The constructor `ClassName(String, int, int, int, int, long)` is undefined.

Your constructor has three `int`s and a `long`; you're trying to pass four `int`s and a `long`.

#### IV

> Assuming this is the right way to iterate, here's what I'd assume would work:
>
> ```
> for (int i = 0; i < hList.size(); i++)
> {
>     System.out.println(hList[i].currentDate);
> }
> ```

A for each loop is better if you don't need the index variable `i`.

```
 for (ClassName item: list) {
     System.out.println(item.currentDate);
 }
```

If you do want `i` then change `[i]` to `.get(i)`. Java doesn't have operator overloading, so `[]` is only available on arrays, not classes or interfaces like `List`.

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    System.out.println(list.get(i).currentDate);
}
```

Comment: So that's Java's foreach loop! Thank you. I did think about using `this.var`, but I wasn't sure if it would work. Maybe I should've tried that instead! Let's assume I do need the index (I like to know how to use both properly), when I use `hList[i].var`, I get this error: `The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to ArrayList<ClassName>`

Comment: You cannot access the backing array of a `List` in java by index like that (assuming it even *is* an array).  You have to use `list.get(i)` instead of `list[i]`.

Comment: Thank you. And when trying to use your `List<ClassName>` suggestion, I get this error: `The type List is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments <ClassName>`. I've tried it, and someone suggested I use `ArrayList`. Not sure if that's the right way to do it.

Comment: Make sure you are using `java.util.List` and not `java.awt.List`.

Comment: Yep, that's the problem! I was using `java.awt.List`.

Comment: Another thing that frequently gets lost in translation between C# and Java is that Java's `List` is equivalent to C#'s `IList`.  It's an *interface* not a class.

Comment: `II` The OP adds to the `ArrayList`. Therefore, `Collection` or `Iterable` are immediately eliminated, but even `List`, as `add` is documented as being *optional*. Best use an implementation that you know actually does what you need. (e.g. `Arrays.asList` and try to add to that list).

Comment: `add` being *optional* means that read-only collections are permissible. Since the concrete class here is `ArrayList`, we know that `add` will work. `Arrays.asList` by contrast is fixed size. That wouldn't work.

Comment: Since you're teaching conventions (up-vote for that), you might also mention that public fields are discouraged. Your `println(item)` should be `println(item.currentDate)` to be consistent with example, or `println(item.getCurrentDate())` if you decide to use accessors in the examples.

Answer (score 3):

You're adding an extra int in the constructor of your class, it takes 1 String, 3 ints and 1 long, and you're trying to create it with 1 String, 4 ints and 1 Long.
And the way of iterate your list is

```
  for (ClassName element:hList){
        //something meaningful here 
        System.out.println(element.currentDate);
  }
```

You could also use a Java 8 feature :)

```
hList.forEach(className -> {
     System.out.println(className.currentDate);
});
```

Comment: Nit: 1 *long*. Sorry to quibble, but they are different types.