# How to stop the shape from disappearing when you click on new location?

Tags: java, jframe, jpanel, mouseevent, actionlistener

I have written this code that displays a shape on a mouse click, but I have problem. When I click on new location the shape disappear on the previous one. How can I stop that from happening?

First Class:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class MouseClick {
    private static int x,y;
    private static DrawingObjects object = new DrawingObjects();

    public static void main(String[] args){

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("MouseClick");
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(400, 400);
        frame.add(object);
        object.addMouseListener(new AL());
    }
    static class AL extends MouseAdapter{
        public void mouseClicked (MouseEvent e){
            x = e.getX();
            y = e.getY();
            object.drawing(x, y);
        }
    }
}
```

Second Class:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class DrawingObjects extends JPanel{
    private static int x,y;

    public void drawing(int xx, int yy){
        x = xx;
        y = yy;
        repaint();
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.fillRect(x, y, 20, 20);
    }
}
```

Comment: You are storing only the last clicked location in the `DrawingObjects` class. So the previous rectangles you have drawn earlier would disappear.

Comment: @Blip So I should use arraylist?

Comment: Yes you have to use a List to store the previous clicked points

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to handle this is to keep track of every point that's been clicked on, and redraw each one in `paintComponent`.

So change `private static int x, y` to `private List<Point> points = new ArrayList<>()`, and add into that instead:

```
public void drawing(int x, int y){
    points.add(new Point(x, y));
    repaint();
}
```

Then go through each point when you redraw:

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    super.paintComponent(g);
    for(Point p : points){
        g.fillRect(p.x, p.y, 20, 20);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do I have to change anything in the first class?

Comment: @ItssMohammed I don't think you should need to, although I haven't tested this yet.

Comment: @ItssMohammed Okay, I've tested, and you don't need to change anything in the first class. The only things that need to change which I didn't mention are the imports. Both `List` and `ArrayList` are in the `java.util` package.

Comment: It worked after I changed it to: private ArrayList<Point> points = new ArrayList<>() because I got an error.. is there a problem with this change?

Comment: @ItssMohammed Doing it that way is fine; it doesn't really matter in this situation. If you want to know about the reasoning for declaring it one way vs. the other, see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2279030/type-list-vs-type-arraylist-in-java)