# Inserting a String[] into a String[] in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, string

How do you add a `String[]` into a `String[]` in Java? To be more clear, my desired output is:

```
String[][] out = {{"A", "AA"},{"B", "BB"}};
```

I don't know the size of the output array, it can contain more then two elements. Basically, I wanted to do it like this (don't mind the syntax it's a blend of Python):

```
String [] out;
String[] temp = {"A","AA"};
out.append(temp)
```

So now out should look like `{{"A","AA"}}`. Then I can append `{"B", "BB"}` creating the desire output above? This is what my thought was, but I'm not sure if it can be done. I am more experienced with Python and it can be done in Python, but I am wanting to do this in Java. Any ideas?

Comment: Arrays are always fixed-size.  You may be looking for a `List<List<String>>`.

Comment: Or possibly a `List<String[]>` if the OP really wants string arrays at the end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As in the comment mentioned, you can use the `List` to store all the array values inside.

It is when you put in:

```
List<String[]> list = new ArrayList<>();
String[] array = {"A", "B"};
list.add(array);
...
```

And it is when you get out:

```
String[] array = list.get(0 /*i*/);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using List for this purpose as you would have more operations to perform on Lists than an Array.

```
List<List<String>> out = new ArrayList<>();
List<String> temp = new ArrayList<String>();
temp.add("A");
temp.add("AA");
out.add(temp);
```

Read through the Javadocs for more on this.

Answer (score 2):

You can either use List or ArrayList that dynamically grows.

```
  ArrayList al = new ArrayList();
```

The ArrayList class extends AbstractList and implements the List interface. ArrayList supports dynamic arrays that can grow as needed.

Standard Java arrays are of a fixed length. After arrays are created, they cannot grow or shrink, which means that you must know in advance how many elements an array will hold.

Array lists are created with an initial size. When this size is exceeded, the collection is automatically enlarged. When objects are removed, the array may be shrunk.

For differences between List and ArrayList [Type List vs type ArrayList in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2279030/type-list-vs-type-arraylist-in-java)

[Detailed Methods of ArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)

You could try this way too if you exactly want to add dynamic array of Strings into another dynamic array.

```
List<List<String>> addresses = new ArrayList<List<String>>();

ArrayList<String> singleAddress = new ArrayList<String>();
singleAddress.add("17 Fake Street");
singleAddress.add("Phoney town");
singleAddress.add("Makebelieveland");

addresses.add(singleAddress);
```

Answer (score 2):

Because in Java, **Array** is a fixed length data structure so you should try java `List` which supports dynamically insertion and deletion of elements. An example using `java.util.ArrayList` is following:

```
java.util.List<String[]> out = new java.util.ArrayList<String[]>();
String[] temp = {"A","AA"};
out.add(temp);//insertion
```

And using index (started from `0`), we can get element like `out.get(0);` and can remove element like `out.remove(0);`