# handeling input using a for/while statament and array JAVA

Tags: java, arrays

I know this might not be the best way of scanning for input and printing it out but I want to figure out if it's possible.
I keep getting a runtime error. what am I doing wrong?
the input is 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
and I want the computer to stop processing the input when it gets to 3 so that it prints only 1-3 to the standard output window.
any feedback would be great. thank you

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class numRewrite {
  public static void main(String[] args) {    
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    int[] numInput = {};
    int numPlace;

    for(numPlace = 0;numPlace < 4;numPlace++) {
        numInput[numPlace] = input.nextInt();
    }

    while(numInput[numPlace]!= 4) {
        System.out.println(numInput[numPlace]);     
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Your array has length 0, because you create it with ```{}```. That means you can not store anything in it.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few confusing things happening:

- Your `input` variable is an `int` array and you initialize it with a length of zero. If you want to use a list that grows as you add things to it I suggest using a real `List` type. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2279030/type-list-vs-type-arraylist-in-java).
- You're also not ever incrementing your `numplace` variable in the while loop which means you'll print the same value out forever.

Zin Minn makes a good point, if you really want to use an array rather than a list you can initialize it with a size of 5.

Answer (score 0):

Your code and what you want to achieve do not match. Scanner is used if needed to read input from a user or file. Based of what my understanding is from what you provided i think you are looking for this:

```
public class numRewrite {
  public static void main(String[] args) {  


int[] numInput = {1,2,3,4,5};


for(int numPlace = 0;numPlace < 3;numPlace++) {
    System.out.println(numInput[numPlace]);
    }


   }
}
```

If you are not reading input from a user typing it in then you do not need a Scanner.

If you are looking for input from a user then maybe you are looking for this?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class numRewrite {
  public static void main(String[] args) {    
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    int[] numInput = new int[5];
    int numPlace;

    for(numPlace = 0;numPlace < 5;numPlace++) {
        System.out.println("Enter input: ");
        numInput[numPlace] = input.nextInt();
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        System.out.println(numInput[i]);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have many problems

I think you said that you want the user to input 5 values, and then program should output values 1-3.

You're not incrementing the var in the while loop. You're only going to 3 on your input. You aren't initializing the array.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class numRewrite {
  public static void main(String[] args) {    
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    int[] numInput = new int[5];

    for(int numPlace = 0; numPlace < 5; numPlace++) {
        numInput[numPlace] = input.nextInt();
    }

    while(int numPlace != 3) {
        System.out.println(numInput[numPlace++]);     
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using fixed size **int[]**.

Once you declare this array, you can't change the size.

You can use **ArrayList** because it is not fixed size array and can extendable.

If you want to use **int[]**, you have to initialize the size.

For example :

```
int[] numInput = new int[5];
```

Answer (score -1):

First of all you have to declare numInput array : `int[] numInput = new int[5];`

Read user input using a loop and print only the first three integers that the user typed :

```
for (int numPlace = 0; numPlace < 5; numPlace++) {
 numInput[numPlace] = input.nextInt(); 
  if(numPlace <3) 
     System.out.println(numInput[numPlace]);
    }
```

### Full code :

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    int[] numInput = new int[5];

    for (int numPlace = 0; numPlace < 5; numPlace++) {
        numInput[numPlace] = input.nextInt();
        if (numPlace < 3) {
            System.out.println(numInput[numPlace]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Code only answers aren't really a good fit for this site, we prefer some explanation of what the OP's problem is, and why the code you're offering fixes the problem. Please read [answer]