# What is Difference between List<String> and ArrayList<String>?

Tags: java, list, collections

what is difference between

```
List<String> l1 = new ArrayList<String>();
```

and

```
ArrayList<String> l2 = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Also which one is better to use?

Comment: check this out .. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2279030/type-list-vs-type-arraylist-in-java

Comment: Also please read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/383947/what-does-it-mean-to-program-to-an-interface

Comment: The only reason to use `ArrayList` is if you need to call `ensureCapacity()` or `trimToSize()`.

Comment: @4castle: Or if the use of an array-list is actually relevant in some way.

Comment: `ArrayList<>` is also a promise of O(1) access times, where `List<>` only promises O(N).

Comment: @AJNeufeld please add source of your statement.

Comment: @dkb Sorry, I was referring specifically to `#get(int)` access times.  `ArrayList` implements `RandomAccess`, where as `List` could be a `LinkedList`, which would be O(N).  Of course, this refers to what is promised by the interface to external code; the object will always still be a concrete `ArrayList`.