# Java ArrayList copy constructor

Tags: java, arraylist, constructor, copy, copy-constructor

I have an object `anObject` with two private member variables:

```
public class anObject {
    private String name;
    private ArrayList<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();
}
```

I have a constructor:

```
public anObject() {
    name = "";
}
```

I have my copy constructors:

```
public anObject(anObject copy) {
this();
newObject(copy);
}

public void newObject(anObject copyTwo) {
    name = copyTwo.name;
    // How to deep copy an ArrayList?
}
```

But how can I "deep copy" all the elements of my ArrayList in `copyTwo`, to my `this.myList`?

I have looked at the other questions on SO but their ArrayLists all contain objects whereas mine just contains Strings. Thanks for any help!

Comment: What makes you think a `String` is not an object?

Comment: If you want a deep copy for your list, you just need a foreach in your list

Comment: `ArrayList` has a [copy constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#ArrayList(java.util.Collection)), you can use that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

create a new reference to list, since your list is holding strings and strings are immutable you can do:

```
List<String> copyString = new ArrayList<>(original);
```

Comment: So this won't be a problem with what I have been seeing as a "Shallow Copy"? I don't want changes to one object to affect the other.

Comment: You are using a List of `String`. It cannot .

Comment: @davidxxx great Thanks!

Comment: Java strings are immutable, so that won't be a problem. If the list would contain mutable reference types, you would need to deep copy the elements as well.

Comment: @MickMnemonic Gotcha. And do I have to create a `List` or can I still use an `ArrayList`?

Comment: Declaring the field a `List` is called programming to the interface, which is a preferred way to write code. [This thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2279030/type-list-vs-type-arraylist-in-java) has some reasons why.

Answer (score 1):

You can deep copy using a new collection. Changes in new collection won't affect the previous list

```
List<String> copyTwo= new ARrayList<String>();
copyTwo.addAll(myList );
```

Comment: Why not: `List<String> copyTwo= new ArrayList<String>(myList);`?

Comment: Hi, here on stackoverflow, we don't just provide the questioneer with code.  We provide them with an explanation of why this will solve their problem, or how it works.  Please edit your answer to reflect this mentality :)

Comment: another option to do that

Comment: @assylias Do I have to use `List` or can I still use `ArrayList`?