# Java arrayList incompatible with Vector

Tags: java, arraylist, vector, collections

I have code as below

```
private Vector<Vector<Object>> barCode;

private boolean isBarCode(String temp) {
        for (Vector<Object> link : barCode) {
            if (link.get(0).toString().equals(temp)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

I am getting below error.

`Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList incompatible with java.util.Vector`

at the for loop line.

Any input please?

Comment: The bug is not in the code you posted. Please include a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

```
private List<List<Object>> barCode;

private boolean isBarCode(String temp) {
    for (List<Object> link : barCode) {
        if (link.get(0).toString().equals(temp)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

[Use the interface, not the implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2279030/type-list-vs-type-arraylist-in-java). `Vector` and `ArrayList` both implement the `List` interface, so this allows instances of either (and any other implementation). I would also recommend standardizing on creating `ArrayList` instances in the rest of your code, except where you're sure you need the features of [other implementations](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/implementations/list.html).

Answer (score 0):

Your `barCode` contains `ArrayList` instead of `Vector`.

Someone put wrong container. It is not enough data in your example to find out where and why.

You can replace `for (Vector<Object> link : barCode)` to `for (ArrayList<Object> link : barCode)` and `Vector<Vector<Object>> barCode` to `Vector<ArrayList<Object>> barCode`, but I strongly suggest you **not to do it** before your find out why `barCode` contains `ArayList`.

It is happened because somewhere in your code raw generics are used (`Vector` without generic parameters).