# Can we use ArrayList to store WebElements?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, arraylist

Below code works fine when i use `List` instead of `ArrayList`,

```
ArrayList<WebElement> list= driver.findElements(locator);
```

I want to understand why I can't use `ArrayList` here? Is it used to store specific type of elements?

Comment: Just give it a try and check is it working.

Comment: Here is a past response that should help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2279030/type-list-vs-type-arraylist-in-java

Comment: Did you check the return type of [`findElements()`](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.html#findElements-org.openqa.selenium.By-)?

Comment: @shmosel Thanks just checked , it has return type as list and therefore the code worked after casting

Comment: Don't cast. It's none of your business that it happens to be an `ArrayList`. The `List` interface gives you all the functionality you need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`WebDriver#findElements(...)`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.html#findElements-org.openqa.selenium.By-) returns a `java.util.List`:

> `java.util.List<WebElement> findElements(By by)`
>
> Find all elements within the current page using the given mechanism.
>   This method is affected by the 'implicit wait' times in force at the
>   time of execution. When implicitly waiting, this method will return as
>   soon as there are more than 0 items in the found collection, or will
>   return an empty list if the timeout is reached.
>
> **Parameters**: `by` - The locating mechanism to use
>
> **Returns**: A list of all `WebElements`, or an empty list if nothing
>   matches

Knowing that `List` is an interface and `ArrayList` is a concrete implementation (class) of that interface, the documentation does not specify if the `List` returned is an `ArrayList` or not. If it were you could simply cast it to `ArrayList`.

So, since the concrete type is unknown...

...if you want an `ArrayList`, you have to [construct](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#ArrayList-java.util.Collection-) one from the list returned:

```
ArrayList<WebElement> list = new ArrayList<>(driver.findElements(locator));
```

That's the only reliable method. Casting may work for some driver implementations but not for others.

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation !!

Answer (score 0):

List is an Interface and ArrayList is an implementation. Similarly, List has other [implementations](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/implementations/list.html) too. So what `driver.findElements(locator)` method returns may be some other implementation of List Interface. Of course, this is just an educated guess, as I don't know what `findElements` method returns

Answer (score 0):

Got the answer , findElements has return type as list and therefore the code worked after casting

```
ArrayList<WebElement> list=(ArrayList<WebElement>) driver.findElements(locator);
```

Comment: Working code is not the same thing as correct code.

Comment: @shmosel yeah i understand , was just curious to know , thanks a lot for your help.