# Append to File & Read from File, but nothing happens

Tags: java, file

I am trying to write a program that creates a kind of database in a file. Its base functions are Read all records and Append a new record to file, but every time I try to append something nothing happens.

Here is my code:

```java
public class SavingInFile {
    FileWriter example=new FileWriter("template.txt",true);
    FileReader example2=new FileReader("template.txt");
    BufferedWriter setNewRecord=new BufferedWriter(example);
    BufferedReader readTheRecords=new BufferedReader(example2);

    public SavingInFile() throws IOException {
    }

    void safeNewData(PersonRecord anotherPersonRecord) throws IOException {
        setNewRecord=new BufferedWriter(example);
        setNewRecord.append(anotherPersonRecord.addNewRecord());

    }

     ArrayList<PersonRecord> getDataFromFile() throws IOException {
        setNewRecord=new BufferedWriter(example);

        readTheRecords=new BufferedReader(example2);
         ArrayList<PersonRecord> valuesKeeper = new ArrayList<>();


         System.out.println(readTheRecords.readLine());

        while(readTheRecords.readLine()!=null) {
            if(readTheRecords.readLine()!=null) {
                String[] tempArray = readTheRecords.readLine().split(";");
                PersonRecord tempRecord = new PersonRecord();
                tempRecord.name = tempArray[0];
                tempRecord.age = Integer.parseInt(tempArray[1]);
                tempRecord.surname = tempArray[2];
                tempRecord.salary = Integer.parseInt(tempArray[3]);
            }
        }

        this.setNewRecord.close();
        return valuesKeeper;
    }

    public void displayArrayList() throws IOException {
        ArrayList<PersonRecord> example=this.getDataFromFile();
        Iterator<PersonRecord> iterateValues=example.iterator();

        while(iterateValues.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println(iterateValues.next().name+ " "+iterateValues.next().surname+ " "+iterateValues.next().age+ "  " + iterateValues.next().salary+ " ");
        }
    }

    public void closeBuffers() throws IOException {
        this.readTheRecords.close();
    }
}
```

This is a Person Class, which contains dataFields

```
public class PersonRecord {
    int age;
    double salary;
    String name;
    String surname;

    public PersonRecord() {
    }

    public PersonRecord(int age, double salary, String name, String surname) {
        this.age = age;
        this.salary = salary;
        this.name = name;
        this.surname = surname;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public double getSalary() {
        return salary;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getSurname() {
        return surname;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public void setSalary(double salary) {
        this.salary = salary;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setSurname(String surname) {
        this.surname = surname;
    }

    String addNewRecord() {
        return this.name+";"+this.surname+";"+String.valueOf(this.age)+";"+String.valueOf(this.salary);
    }
}
```

and here is my main:

```java
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        SavingInFile bufferToFile = new SavingInFile();
        ArrayList<PersonRecord> keepRecords=bufferToFile.getDataFromFile();

        PersonRecord x = new PersonRecord(10,13,"34","45");

        bufferToFile.saveNewData(x);
        ArrayList<PersonRecord> example=bufferToFile.getDataFromFile();
        bufferToFile.displayArrayList();
        bufferToFile.closeBuffers();
    }
}
```

***Any suggestions about what is wrong there?***

Comment: I see you have valuesKeeper in getDataFromFile() but do not append any values to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has a lot of "bad smells" places. Just go through the following resources:

- [Type List vs type ArrayList in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2279030/type-list-vs-type-arraylist-in-java)
- [Reading file in Java](https://www.baeldung.com/reading-file-in-java)
- [Java – Try with Resources](https://www.baeldung.com/java-try-with-resources)
- you shadowed some parameters at your method and didn't close it correctly after using
- formatting your code help a lot (exactly before posting it like a question)
- meaningfully named variables help read and to maintain code

So following is the rewritten solution

Record class:

```
@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
class PersonRecord {
    String name;
    String surname;
    int age;
    double salary;

    String addNewRecord() {
        return String.format("%s;%s;%s;%s\n", this.name, this.surname, this.age, this.salary);
    }
}
```

Turn separate utility class for processing operation with the file for persons:

```
final class PersonOperations {
    private Personoperations() {
    }

    public static void appendToFile(String fileName, List<PersonRecord> persons) throws IOException {
        @Cleanup
        BufferedWriter buffWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(fileName, true));

        for (PersonRecord person : persons) {
            buffWriter.append(person.addNewRecord());
        }
    }

    public static List<PersonRecord> readFile(String fileName) throws IOException {
        @Cleanup
        BufferedReader buffReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
        List<PersonRecord> persons = buffReader.lines()
                .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                .map(str -> {
                    String[] temp = str.split(";");
                    return PersonRecord.builder()
                            .name(temp[0])
                            .surname(temp[1])
                            .age(Integer.parseInt(temp[2]))
                            .salary(Double.parseDouble(temp[3]))
                            .build();
                })
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        System.out.println("persons from file: " + persons);
        return persons;
    }

    public static void displayPersons(List<PersonRecord> persons) {
        for (PersonRecord person : persons) {
            System.out.println(person);
        }
    }
}
```

Final demo code will look like:

```
public class FileDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String fileName = "template.txt";

        List<PersonRecord> records = PersonOperations.readFile(fileName);
        PersonOperations.displayPersons(records);

        PersonRecord personRecord = new PersonRecord("Bob", "Dilan", 34, 4500);
        PersonOperations.appendToFile(fileName, List.of(personRecord));

        List<PersonRecord> persons = PersonOperations.readFile(fileName);
        PersonOperations.displayPersons(persons);
    }
}
```

Also, if we don't need any operation with a result from the file, we could add static import and write:

```
displayPersons(readFile(fileName));
```

Console output:

```
persons from file: [PersonRecord(name=Garry, surname=Ford, age=45, salary=6000.0)]
PersonRecord(name=Garry, surname=Ford, age=45, salary=6000.0)
persons from file: [PersonRecord(name=Garry, surname=Ford, age=45, salary=6000.0), PersonRecord(name=Bob, surname=Dilan, age=34, salary=4500.0)]
PersonRecord(name=Garry, surname=Ford, age=45, salary=6000.0)
PersonRecord(name=Bob, surname=Dilan, age=34, salary=4500.0)
```

`template.txt` file ***before execution***:

```
Garry;Ford;45;6000
```

`template.txt` ***after execution***:

```
Garry;Ford;45;6000 
Bob;Dilan;34;4500.0
```

Also, I used [Lombok framework](https://projectlombok.org/) annotations there. You can keep native getters and setters as well. And closing resources after reading it (with Autocloseable or with finally block).

As alternatives for saving to `txt` file you could consider:

- Serialisation: [Java Serialisation](https://www.baeldung.com/java-serialization)
- Serialisation to the XML file.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, when you use FileWrite and BufferWriter you have to make sure to close this them or to use try with resources and below will solve your issue:
And I strongly suggest rewriting everything in a cleaner way.

```
void safeNewData(PersonRecord anotherPersonRecord) throws IOException {
    try (FileWriter example = new FileWriter("template.txt", true); BufferedWriter newRec = new BufferedWriter(example)){
        newRec.write(anotherPersonRecord.addNewRecord());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: check below link it will help you:
https://mkyong.com/java8/java-8-stream-read-a-file-line-by-line/ 
https://mkyong.com/java/java-how-to-create-and-write-to-a-file/
https://mkyong.com/java/how-to-write-to-file-in-java-bufferedwriter-example/