# Java good HashMap practices? ( static final HashMap )

Tags: java, hashmap

```java
    private static final HashMap<String, Commande> COMMAND_DIRECTORY = new HashMap<>();

    static {
        COMMAND_DIRECTORY.put("help", new Help());
    }
```

Does this block of code contain bad HashMap practices?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2279030/829571

Comment: @assylias it sure would be nice to have a descriptive comment with that link!  Even better, you could flag close for duplicate assuming that is what you're saying it is, but with no comment I'm not sure that is what you're saying.  Since you didn't say what you're saying.

Comment: @ebyrob Based on the content of the linked Q&A I believe assylias is simply saying the variable's declared type should typically be `Map` instead of `HashMap`.

Comment: @ebyrob That block of code compile. It passes all the unit tests of the project, I am in the refactoring phase.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## `Map.of`

The most recent versions of Java offer the `Map.of` methods to produce an unmodifiable `Map` object with convenient literal syntax.

```
private static final Map < String , Command > commands = 
    Map.of (
        "help", new Help() , 
        "whatever" , new Whatever() 
    )
;
```

As others mentioned, best to declare your variables to be of a more abstract type, a more general interface or superclass, rather than a narrow concrete type. So better to declare the variable as `Map` than `HashMap`. And in the case of this Answer’s code, we *must* declare as `Map` because we do not know what concrete class might be instantiated by `Map.of`.

As others noted, generally best to use all uppercase names only where the named object is deeply immutable.

Comment: Thank you very much for this beautiful code, but I wanted to get a deeply immutable object.

Comment: So if I understood correctly with Map.of we will still retain the advantages of the HashMap? But we let Java choose the right structure?

Comment: @JavaMan: There is no map implementation that can make it _deeply_ immutable.  The one and only way to make it deeply immutable is for you to make your `Command` class deeply immutable.  But yes, `Map.of` will choose the right map implementation for you.

Comment: @LouisWasserman Command is an interface. How do you declare a class as a deeply immutable class?
With a Singleton pattern?

Comment: That's...one way, but certainly not the only way.  Just follow the normal rules for making something immutable, and make sure every field does the same.

Comment: @JavaMan For an excellent example of immutable class design in Java, look at the *java.time* classes built into Java 8 and later.

Answer (score 3):

It's not recommended to write it like this:

```
HashMap<String, Commande> COMMAND_DIRECTORY = new HashMap<>();
```

The better way is to write it like this:

```
Map<String, Commande> COMMAND_DIRECTORY = new HashMap<>();
```

In this way, if in the future you decide to choose a different `Map` implementation it will be more simple, as you are not restricted to a specific implementation.

Comment: I think "not ok" is overstating it a bit. Your "better way" is definitely better though.

Comment: Usually.. but I disagree with your phrasing. It's not `not ok` to write it in the first way, it's just more restricting and that's either better or worse depending on your intent..

Comment: Changed "not ok" to " not recommended", maybe makes more sense like this.

Answer (score 3):

Yes.  Leaving a mutable `Map` as a static final is problematic.

```
private static final Map<String, Commande> COMMAND_DIRECTORY;

static {
    Map<String, Commande> directory = new HashMap<>();
    directory.put("help", new Help());
    COMMAND_DIRECTORY = Collections.unmodifiableMap(directory);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

i would rather dodge the screaming case variables, ide will show you that something is final, you even write final before the declaration. To the `static {}`, noone uses it, from my point of view it looks little too indirect thus there is what i would write.

```
 private static final HashMap<String, Commande> commandDirectory = new HashMap<String, Commande>(){{
   put("help", new Help())
}};
```

this is what i see in serious code bases anyway

Comment: This is certainly convenient, but wouldn't be a best practice. This creates a new _class_ that extends `HashMap`. If you do this a lot, it can create problems with garbage collection because you have a lot of new classes stuck in the classloader.

Comment: oh i did not know that that happens, strangly enough java game mindustry uses this for all content-type-definitions. Though we have to consider that field is static and final so object will never be collected, or at most it will when program terminates.

Comment: I do a lot of SQL and C#, but to me this coding style looks quite horrific.  long line length.  I assume there will be about 50 entries next to "help".  When I read the code I want to see a very short variable definition for `commandDirectory` all by itself and then very obvious one-line per entry table of key to obvious data object.