# How to add to ArrayList continuously

Tags: java, arrays, swing, arraylist

What I am trying to achieve here is when the user selects the data in the ComboBox, it will match it to my HashMap, and add it to an ArrayList.

```
public class Stuffs {

Stuffs(){
    
    //Creating HashMap
    HashMap<String,String> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("LOTR 1", "The Fellowship of the Ring");
    map.put("LOTR 2", "The Two Towers");
    map.put("LOTR 3", "The Return of the King");
    
    //Creating frame
    JFrame f = new JFrame();
    f.setSize(500, 500);
    f.setVisible(true);
    
    //Creating combobox
    String choices[] = {"LOTR 1","LOTR 2","LOTR 3"};
    JComboBox cb = new JComboBox(choices);
    cb.setBounds(50, 50,90,20);
    f.setLayout(null);    
    f.setSize(300,300);
    f.add(cb);

    //Creating button
    JButton btn = new JButton("OK");
    btn.setBounds(100,100,70,20); 
    f.add(btn);
    
    
    //Get selected item from HashMap and add into arraylist
    btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        
        ArrayList test = new ArrayList<>();
        String x = (String) cb.getSelectedItem();
        String y = map.get(x);
        Collections.addAll(test, x, y);
        System.out.println(test);
        }
    });
    
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    new Stuffs();     
}      
    }
```

The code works. The output is :

```
[LOTR 1, The Fellowship of the Ring]
```

(User selected LOTR 1 from the ComboBox)

But when I click on the button again, the ArrayList resets. What I want is so that the ArrayList keeps on adding data without replacing the initial ones, even if its repetitive. For example:

```
[LOTR 1, The Fellowship of the Ring, LOTR 2, The Two Towers]
```

Basically the user can select from the ComboBox countless of times, and the ArrayList keeps adding up and adding up.

Comment: Make a field for that arraylist and use that. You need something that lasts longer than a method invocation. That is what fields are for.

Comment: unrelated: __never-ever__ do any manual sizing or locating, instead use a suitable layoutManager

Answer (score 2):

As currently written, your locally declared `ArrayList` is being discarded (headed for garbage collection) each time the flow of control exits your action listener.

Move the list declaration outside that method, to be a member field. (As [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73309203/how-to-add-to-arraylist-continuously/73309787#comment129465546_73309203).)

And generally best to declare the more general type, a `List` rather than `ArrayList`. (See [this Question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2279030/642706).)

And use [Java Generics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generics_in_Java) rather than raw types. Add `< String >`.

```
public class Stuffs {
    // Member fields
    List < String > test = new ArrayList<>();

    // Constructor
    Stuffs(){ … }
}
```

As a member field of the `Stuffs` class, the list stays around for as long as the instance object of `Stuffs` lives.

---

Be aware of [thread-safety](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_safety). As currently written, the `ArrayList` should only be accessed from the user-interface thread. If any other threads will access the list, you’ll need to take steps to protect that resource in a thread-safe manner.

Comment: Since this will likely become the accepted answer, may I also recommend making the function synchronous since ArrayLists are not thread safe and the user has mentioned user-triggered events.

Comment: I hope we can also place the `test` as a field of the anonymous inner class

Comment: @tresf As currently written, that list is accessed only by the user-interface thread. So no need to change the code. But your Comment prompted me to add a note about thread safety. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, the code didn't use actions (likely intentionally dumbed-down), but the description did, and it's a pitfall that's easy to get blindsided by.  Note, I had to research the reasoning to use a `List`.  I was unaware the interface provides nearly all of the `ArrayList` functionality.  I found a nice explanation which may be beneficial to the OP here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2279079/3196753

Comment: @tresf Thanks. I added that link to the Answer.