# Instantiating List generics with List<type> vs ArrayList<type>

Tags: java

Teaching myself java and am a little confused on the differences between the two methods of creating a List type object.

What's the difference between:

```
List<type> listvar = new ArrayList<type>();
```

and

```
ArrayList<type> listvar = new ArrayList<type>();
```

Comment: In the first example `listvar` has the type `List<type>`, in the second, it has the type `ArrayList<type>`. That's the only difference. So in the second case we could call `listvar.trimToSize()`, which does not exist on `List`, only on `ArrayList`.

Comment: @tgdavies so correct me if I'm wrong but the first one is type list and second is type arraylist but since List is an interface and can't be instantiated, the `new ArrayList<type>()` in both just uses the ArrayList constructor?

Comment: The right hand side of the assignment is exactly the same in both cases -- an ArrayList instance is created. You could write `Object listvar = new ArrayList<type>();` and an ArrayList is still created.

Comment: This question and its answers might help  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383947/what-does-it-mean-to-program-to-an-interface

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Type List vs type ArrayList in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2279030/type-list-vs-type-arraylist-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

ArrayList is a class while List is an interface.
this is why you can do `new ArrayList<type>` but not `new List<type>`

If you do `List<type> listvar = new ArrayList<type>();` you create a reference of ArrayList which can only use the functionality which the List interface defines.

In both cases you still have an ArrayList.

Comment: You are *not* creating a "version of ArrayList". An *identical* ArrayList is created in both cases. The reference listvar has a different type in each case, and the reference can only be used to call methods present in that type, but the objects are identical.

Comment: @tgdavies thank you for your input. I have edited my answer to be more clear.