# Get last X items of a list in java

Tags: java, list

I can only seem to find answers about last/first element in a list or that you can get a specific item etc.

Lets say I have a list of 100 elements, and I want to return the last 40 elements. How do I do that? I tried doing this but it gave me one element..

```
Post last40posts = posts.get(posts.size() -40);
```

Comment: Refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2895342/java-how-can-i-split-an-arraylist-in-multiple-small-arraylists. You can use `subList` from `size() - 40` to `size()` to get the last 40 elements. Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1279476/truncating-a-list-to-a-given-number-of-elements-in-java (or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12099721/how-to-use-sublist)

Comment: What about `subList`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java: how can I split an ArrayList in multiple small ArrayLists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2895342/java-how-can-i-split-an-arraylist-in-multiple-small-arraylists)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Do use the method sub list

```
List<Post> myLastPosts = posts.subList(posts.size()-40, posts.size());
```

Comment: Strictly, this gets the last 39 elements of the list, as the second argument of `subList` is exclusive.

Comment: what happens if the list is of smaller length than the size we want, ie. the list contains only 5 elements.

Comment: @BrunoFinger if that happens, you will get and IndexOutOfBoundsException. But i would like to know how to fix it.

Comment: Why did you spam the tag arraylist if this is for simpe lists only and not ArrayList bro?

Answer (score 6):

(To complete Ankit Malpani answer)
If `40` is provided by our lovely users, then you will have to restrict it to the list size:

```
posts.subList(posts.size()-Math.min(posts.size(),40), posts.size())
```

Another way to show it:

```
@Test
public void should_extract_last_n_entries() {
    List<String> myList = Arrays.asList("0","1","2","3","4");
    int myListSize = myList.size();
    log.info(myList.subList(myListSize,myListSize).toString());   // output : []
    log.info(myList.subList(myListSize-2,myListSize).toString()); // output : [3, 4]
    log.info(myList.subList(myListSize-5,myListSize).toString()); // output : [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
    int lastNEntries = 50; // now use user provided int
    log.info(myList.subList(myListSize-Math.min(myListSize,lastNEntries),myListSize).toString());
                          // output : [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
    // log.info(myList.subList(myListSize-lastNEntries,myListSize).toString());
                          // ouch IndexOutOfBoundsException: fromIndex = -45
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code will give you only a single element.
You need to use subList method like:

```
posts.subList(posts.size()-40, posts.size())
```