# I cannot remove null values from array output

Tags: java, arrays, string, java.util.scanner

I want the folowing program to take user input, store it in the array then repeat it back when the user types `stop`.

However it prints out the rest of the values upto 100 as `null`, this is what I need to remove. I've tried a few different methods but it's just not working for me.

This is basically what I've got so far (with help from other questions on Stack):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String[] teams = new String[100];
    String str = null;
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int count = -1;
    String[] refinedArray = new String[teams.length];

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {       
       str= sc.nextLine();


       for(String s : teams) {
           if(s != null) { // Skips over null values. Add "|| "".equals(s)" if you want to exclude empty strings
               refinedArray[++count] = s; // Increments count and sets a value in the refined array
           }
       }

       if(str.equals("stop")) {
          Arrays.stream(teams).forEach(System.out::println);
       }

       teams[i] = str;
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe you can convert teams to a List and then truncate it like it says at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1279476/truncate-a-list-to-a-given-number-of-elements

Comment: @ZeldaZach there is no need to truncate a `List` in this case. It will contain only the elements that were added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An array as has a fixed size and if you use an array of an any class, you will have null value for indexes of the values not valued.

If you want to have a array with only used values, you could define a variable to store the size really used by array.
And use it to create a new array with the actual size.

Otherwise you could use the original array but iterating only until the actual size of the array when you loop on `String[] teams`.

```
String[] teams = new String[100];
int actualSize = 0;
...
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {       
   ...

   teams[i] = str;
   actualSize++;
   ...
}
   ...
String[] actualTeams = new String[actualSize];
System.arraycopy(array, 0, actualTeams, 0, actualSize);
```

**A better way is of course using a structure that adjusts automatically its size such as an `ArrayList`.**

Answer (score 1):

You just need to tell your stream what elements to include. You can change the line constructing the stream:

```
   if(str.equals("stop")) {
      //stream is called with a beginning and an end indexes.
      Arrays.stream(teams, 0, i).forEach(System.out::println);
   }
```